# Generating a PNG with matplotlib when DISPLAY is undefined

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to use networkx with Python. When I run this program it get this error. Is there anything missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
#nx.draw_graphviz(G)
#nx_write_dot(G, 'node.png')
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("/var/www/node.png")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 13, in <module>
    nx.draw(G)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 124, in draw
    cf=pylab.gcf()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 90, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

---

I get a different error now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('Agg')

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
#nx.draw_graphviz(G)
#nx_write_dot(G, 'node.png')
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("/var/www/node.png")
```

---

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/__init__.py:835: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  if warn: warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 15, in <module>
    nx.draw(G)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/networkx-1.2.dev-py2.5.egg/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 124, in draw
    cf=pylab.gcf()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 90, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

---

I get a different error now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.use('Agg')

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_nodes_from([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
#nx.draw_graphviz(G)
#nx_write_dot(G, 'node.png')
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("/var/www/node.png")
```

---

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/__init__.py:835: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

  if warn: warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 15, in <module>
    nx.draw(G)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/networkx-1.2.dev-py2.5.egg/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 124, in draw
    cf=pylab.gcf()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 90, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating matplotlib graphs without a running X server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server)

Comment: Move the call to matplotlib.use('Agg') above your other imports, in particular it should be before import of matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: @IvoBosticky comment solved it for me as well: The only thing which is misleading is "above your other imports". It should be obvious that you need to import matplotlib before... This is the whole setting that worked for me:              import matplotlib //
matplotlib.use('Agg') // 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Related: ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](/questions/56656777)

Answer (score 534, accepted):

The main problem is that (on your system) matplotlib chooses an x-using backend by default. I just had the same problem on one of my servers.  The solution for me was to add the following code in a place that gets read *before* any other pylab/matplotlib/**pyplot** import:

```
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

The alternative is to [set it](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) in your `.matplotlibrc`

Comment: Important note: .use needs to be called before pyplot is imported. So if you are, for instance, just trying to import pyplot, you need to import matplotlib first, call use, and than import pyplot.

Comment: The above comment is explained more by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706614/1959808).

Comment: How do you "set it in your .matplotlibrc"?

Comment: `backend: agg` in `~/.config/matplotlib'/matplotlibrc` (as an example, seehttp://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#locating-matplotlib-config-dir). See also http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html, which has an example config file at the bottom of the page. Find "agg" on that page and you'll see the config option you need.

Comment: For reference, [here is the link](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server) to the matplotlib documentation that explains this.  (+1, great answer, helped me perfectly!)

Comment: I can't find documentation for this, but based on my experience, if you use `seaborn`, you also need to call `matplotlib.use('Agg')` before `import seaborn`.

Comment: You might have to restart the shell for this to take effect

Comment: See further down http://stackoverflow.com/a/36271874/1358283 for a somewhat cleaner solution using env-vars - no need to modify your python code

Comment: Works flawlessly.  Solved my dilemma where running plotting code on a Raspberry Pi would work, but not on a Macbook Pro.  Way to go.

Comment: works and very importantly as already said --- "place that gets read before any other pylab/matplotlib/pyplot import:" Thanks !!

Comment: Doesn't work. Says `This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.`

Comment: @Dims: it *does* work. Like mentioned in my answer and in other comments, you noeed to call `matplotlib.use()` *before* doing any other matplotlib import (just like the error message says).

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees I'm still getting the error despite the above steps. I'm trying to create and save a scatterplot, and it throws the error when I call plt.scatter(). Is this just not possible?

Comment: For almost everybody, it works. So it *is* definitively possible :-) Make sure you double-check that you (or some library) isn't import pyplot too early. Perhaps the `matplotlibrc` config file helps in your case?

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees imagine several libraries which all wish to be imported first and using each other

Comment: In the end, something somewhere you wrote has to get called first. A django settings file, a `main.py` script, etc. If necessary, write a tiny wrapper script that runs whatever you normally run *after* the `.use()` call.

Comment: @Reinout van Rees  Holy Smokes!  This answer has just solved days of hair pulling and the Question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400461/create-png-without-show-figure/57400587#57400587  Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

Just as a complement of Reinout's answer.

The permanent way to solve this kind of problem is to edit .matplotlibrc file. Find it via

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
# This is the file location in Ubuntu
'/etc/matplotlibrc'
```

Then modify the backend in that file to `backend : Agg`. That is it.

Comment: Pro tip: set `$MATPLOTLIBRC` to the *directory* where you want to throw your own matplotlibrc in.

Comment: Kinda overkill for a problem like this, but I guess if the server is always working headless it makes sense to modify a configuration file.

Would this have any side effects on how matplotlib will function?

Comment: I'm running matplotlib on a web server so this was the answer for me. I have not noticed any side effects.

Answer (score 46):

The clean answer is to take a little bit of time correctly prepare your execution environment.

The first technique you have to prepare your execution environment is to use a `matplotlibrc` file, [as wisely recommended by Chris Q.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13435682/38140), setting

```
backend : Agg
```

in that file. You can even control — with no code changes — [how and where matplotlib looks for and finds the `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

The second technique you have to prepare your execution environment is to use the [`MPLBACKEND` environment variable](http://matplotlib.org/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#envvar-MPLBACKEND) (and inform your users to make use of it):

```
export MPLBACKEND="agg"
python <program_using_matplotlib.py>
```

This is handy because you don't even have to provide another file on disk to make this work. I have employed this approach with, for example, testing in continuous integration, and running on remote machines that do not have displays.

Hard-coding your matplotlib backend to "Agg" in your Python code is like bashing a square peg into a round hole with a big hammer, when, instead, you could have just told matplotlib it needs to be a square hole.

Comment: The second technique looks like the most elegant in this situation.

Comment: Using MPLBACKEND solved it for me. Definitely the most elegant way!

Answer (score 44):

I got the error while using matplotlib through Spark. `matplotlib.use('Agg')` doesn't work for me. In the end, the following code works for me. More [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3466/.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

Comment: This works great, without the restrictions on the order used to import matplotlib and other libraries.

Comment: When running on Spark, did you have to restrict this to run on the head node or did you get this to work when running on worker nodes?

Comment: I'm using this in a django project and this was the only way I could get it working.

Answer (score 31):

I will just repeat what @Ivo Bosticky said which can be overlooked. Put these lines at the **VERY** start of the py file.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Or one would get error

```
*/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py:923: UserWarning:  This call to   matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,*
```

This will resolve all Display issue

Answer (score 17):

I found this snippet to work well when switching between X and no-X environments.

```
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
    mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a superior solution than the one accepted, although it does not directly answer the question, and answers a question not asked.

Answer (score 14):

When signing into the server to execute the code
use this instead:

```
ssh -X username@servername
```

the `-X` will get rid of the no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
error

:)

Comment: I need to use '-X' in order to have the .png image saved. Many thanks.

Comment: This will fail for a long process if ssh times out, or if you need to disconnect for whatever reason. Note that a timeout may even occur if the connecting client goes into sleep.

Comment: You can prevent timeouts by adding `-o ServerAliveCountMax=120 -o ServerAliveInterval=30` which will make ssh client send an empty packet every 30 seconds for max 1 hour.

Answer (score 6):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

What system are you on? It looks like you have a system with X11, but the DISPLAY environment variable was not properly set. Try executing the following command and then rerunning your program:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

Comment: but why does it eed to set a display variable, i am remotely logged on to this server, all it should do is generate a PNG file???

Comment: @krisdigitx, if you are remotely connected, don't set a display variable; instead use the "-XY" flag when you connect. In order to display, it needs to know which Xserver to send the image to; in this case, it would be the display of your computer, instead of the remote computer. Using the "-XY" flag causes SSH to set the DISPLAY variable automatically to point to the display of the connecting computer.

Comment: @krisdigitx, I agree, it is very strange that it does that; my guess, though, is that it paints the image using X11, and then saves the result using X11.

Comment: Using this setting for $DISPLAY doesn't work on EC2 running Ubuntu 16

-- couldn't connect to display "localhost:0"

Answer (score 3):

One other thing to check is whether your current user is authorised to connect to the X display. In my case, root was not allowed to do that and matplotlib was complaining with the same error.

```
user@debian:~$ xauth list         
debian/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ae921efd0026c6fc9d62a8963acdcca0
root@debian:~# xauth add debian/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ae921efd0026c6fc9d62a8963acdcca0
root@debian:~# xterm
```

source: <strike>http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/494</strike> https://debian-administration.org/article/494/Getting_X11_forwarding_through_ssh_working_after_running_su

Answer (score 3):

To make sure your code is portable across Windows, Linux and OSX and for systems with and without displays, I would suggest following snippet:

```
import matplotlib
import os
# must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
if os.name == 'posix' and "DISPLAY" not in os.environ:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')

# now import other things from matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756291/207661

Answer (score 1):

For Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
```

And then to print to file:

```
#PDF build and save
    def multi_page(filename, figs=None, dpi=200):
        pp = PdfPages(filename)
        if figs is None:
            figs = [mpl.pyplot.figure(n) for n in mpl.pyplot.get_fignums()]
        for fig in figs:
            fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight', fig_size=(10, 8))
        pp.close()
```

and to create the PDF:

```
multi_page(report_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

worked for me as long as I was calling the plotting functions/code directly. But if you are using

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

`Parallel` and `delayed` modules for parallelizing your code then you need to add

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'backend': 'Agg'})
```

line inside your function in order for `agg` backend to work.