# Matplotlib: display plot on a remote machine

Tags: python, ssh, matplotlib

I have a python code doing some calculation on a remote machine, named A. I connect on A via `ssh` from a machine named B.
Is there a way to display the figure on machine B?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined?lq=1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use matplotlib on Mac OS X on the remote machine (A), you must first make sure that you use one of the X11-based display back-ends, since the native Mac OS X back-end cannot export its plots to another display.  Selecting a back-end can be achieved with

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK')  # Or any other X11 back-end
```

The list of supported back-ends can be obtained by giving `use()` an incorrect back-end name: matplotlib then prints an error message listing the possible back-ends.

ssh X11 forwarding can then be used to display matplotlib plots (see David Z's answer).

Comment: It'll make you instal `pygtk` to do that, and it seems it's either impossible or a total pain to do that with Python 3.

Comment: This definitely depend on your platform and package manager. On macOS, MacPorts has a py27-pygtk package that should make the install smooth for Python 2.

Comment: @sudo I checked all the supported back-ends. In my case, `TkAgg` and `GTK3Cairo` back-ends worked for Python 3. `TkAgg` seems to be faster.

Comment: If speed is a concern I recommend `-C` flag to SSH

Comment: A is the remote machine...

Comment: Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 40):

Sure, you can enable X11 forwarding. Usually this is done by passing the `-X` or `-Y` option to `ssh` when you connect to the remote computer

```
ssh -X computerA
```

Note that the SSH daemon on computer A will also have to be configured to enable X11 forwarding. This is done by putting

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

in computer A's `sshd_config` configuration file.

If computer A's SSH daemon does not have X11 forwarding enabled, you can always have Python write the result of the calculation to a text file, download it to computer B, and use Matplotlib locally.

Comment: for me it was /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: If you edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then make sure to restart the sshd and/or ssh service. Stupid simple way is to restart your computer, but (at least on linux) you can also restart the service using something like `sudo service sshd restart` as described here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-start-stop-ssh-server/

Comment: There is additional helpful advice on this topic from Gilles, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely).

Answer (score 24):

The following worked for me using Mac OS X on the local machine (machine B) and ubuntu on the remote (machine A).

You need X11 server installed on your local machine to do this.

If you're running a recent version of Mac OSX (OS X Mountain Lion or newer), it would NOT have come with X11 pre-installed (see http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293).  Check if you have X11 by opening up Mac terminal, and run command `xterm`.
If an X11 window opens up, you're all set.  If it says command not found, then go to http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/ and install X11 server.  Then logout and log back in to your mac.

After you log back in, try to run `xterm` command again. It should open up X11 window.
At this point your $DISPLAY variable should also be set correctly.  If it's not set, make sure you've logged in/out since installing X11 from XQuartz.

```
echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-I9I3aI/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Then from your local machine, use ssh -X to remote into remote machine A:

```
ssh -X user@machineA
```

Then on the remote machine:

```
python
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')  #I had to use GTKAgg for this to work, GTK threw errors
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #...  and now do whatever you need...
```

Make sure you call `matplotlib.use` BEFORE importing anything else from `matplotlib` (e.g. `matplotlib.pyplot`)

Other useful troubleshooting tips on using ssh -X :  http://oroborosx.sourceforge.net/remotex.html#usessh

Answer (score 13):

GTK seems impossible to get working on Ubuntu with Python3.  Instead, I used tkagg (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656365/4549682) answer):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Test that it's working with this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I had lots of trouble with both gtk and qt, but this worked great!

Comment: That gives me: `TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`. Any ideas?

Comment: Definitely it solved my problem using python 3.6. Unfortunately displaying the images works really slow, any ideas of how improve the speed. I used ssh -Y -C to access to my remote machine.

Comment: So just put this code in the remote and connect through ssh? really?

Answer (score 5):

I have used IPython to solve the related problem. The steps are as follows:

**Step 1:** Install IPython and Jupyter in the remote machine (A) locally (assuming no root privilege) using the following commands:

```
pip install --user ipython
pip install --user jupyter
```

*Update matplotlib:*

```
pip install --user -U matplotlib
```

**Step 2:**

Run Jupyter with no browser from the code directory in the remote machine (A):

```
cd PATH/TO/THE/CODE
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080
```

After this command, a URL will be given something similar to below:

http://localhost:8080/?token=5528ab1eeb3f621b90b63420f8bbfc510edf71f21437c4e2

**Step 3:**

Now open another terminal in the local machine (B) and connect to the remote machine (A) using ssh:

```
ssh -N -L 8080:localhost:8080 user_id@remote.host
```

The port number has to be same in **step 2** and **step 3**. In this example, the port number is 8080.

**Step 4:**

Copy and paste the URL in the **step 3** to a browser in your local machine (B).

Now, the notebook in the remote machine can be used through the browser and plot can be generated using the data in the remote machine.

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to the original question, but it's a hugely advantageous workaround. If you save figures on the remote machine, you can even open them in the notebook viewer! imo it's even better with jupyter lab.

Answer (score 2):

`export MPLBACKEND="agg"` this worked for me.
obviously you can set it via code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library I created to solve this problem https://pypi.org/project/remote-plot/.

It uses the exact same API as matplotlib, but it renders the plots in a web browser which you can view from your machine B.

Install by:

```
pip install remote_plot
```

And then run in python like this:

```
from remote_plot import plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

By default it opens the rendering on port 8000 but you can modify this easily. If you are connecting via ssh, don't forget to forward the port by adding the following flag to your ssh command:

```
ssh YOUR_USER_NAME@YOUR_MACHINE_IP -L 8000:localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

if that doesn't work you could also try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')
```

this seemed to work for me

Yet, if you are trying to get a GUI working I suggest you look at this link: http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Comment: Welcome to [so].While adding link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the link here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add - if you're on Windows as the local machine, make sure you've set up Xming (an X Windows server) and Putty so you can see the remote Linux graphical applications.

I followed the instructions from here: http://laptops.eng.uci.edu/software-installation/using-linux/how-to-configure-xming-putty to do this. It also sets your display environment and variable so you don't get an error when using `tkagg` as the backend.

Comment: the link is dead 404. Please write the instructions

Comment: This is 3 years ago, and I don't want to spend time going through that and posting here, but I found the contents of the web site from Oct 20, 2020 through Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20201020141458/https://laptops.eng.uci.edu/software-installation/using-linux/how-to-configure-xming-putty
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution (I am actually searching how to do this) is to use VSCode to connect remotely, save the plot and just click the file in VScode which will display it.
It is not ideal but...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mac as a client machine, try this.

You basically need to make sure two things are working properly.

- Using GTK or Cairo as `matplotlib`'s backend.
- Forwarding the display.

### Using GTK or Cairo as `matplotlib`'s backend

If you're using `python3`, you must install `cairocffi`.

```
pip install cairocffi
```

Then use the GTK3Agg as a backend of matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('GTK3Agg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

See following description from [matplotlib document](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/faq/usage_faq.html#gtk-and-cairo) for more detail.

> Both GTK2 and GTK3 have implicit dependencies on PyCairo regardless of
> the specific Matplotlib backend used. Unfortunatly the latest release
> of PyCairo for Python3 does not implement the Python wrappers needed
> for the GTK3Agg backend. **Cairocffi can be used as a replacement which
> implements the correct wrapper.**

### Forwarding the display

1. Install launch the latest version of XQuartz.
2. Connect to the remote server using `ssh -X`. ex) `ssh username@ipaddress -X`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with MacOS and a Linux remote machine.

1. In ~/.ssh/config I added the following. I add this since it's possible that your machine might not be taking the xauth location properly.

```
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

2. ssh -Y machine_name
3. Ran the following dummy program:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = [1,2,3]
    y = [2,4,1]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```