# pyplot while using X11 forwarding

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, x11, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to setup my remote working environment so that I can use `matplotlib.pyplot` under ipython. My local machine and remote machine are both MAC OSX Mavericks. I've tried `xeyes` and it works properly so I think my X11 forwarding works fine. However, when I try functions in `matplotlib.pyplot` it didn't show any error message but I didn't see any figure either.

I know it's about which backend to use and I've tried using `ipython --pylab=tk` but didn't work. Tried to install `pygtk` but can't manage to install a dependency `py2cairo` (seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27485)). Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How did you "try functions in matplotlib.pyplot"?

The following works for me

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```