# matplotlib backend for remote plot display (alternative for gtk/x11) OS X El Capitan with homebrew

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, homebrew, x11

Lost enough time on this one today to justify a post...

I previously relied on GTKAgg matplotlib [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for remote display and interactive plotting from the ipython command line on a remote server. This approach is similar to the one described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453527/1665400

This week I upgraded to El Capitan (10.10.5), and a fresh homebrew install. Everything is working correctly, but I recently learned that the homebrew project dropped x11 support for gtk, and is generally moving toward dropping x11 support entirely.  My github issue is here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/313

I've tried several other backends, and they all seem to be working correctly within the homebrew Python framework, but none have x11 support. Maybe I'm missing an obvious option.

I can potentially build my own gtk against x11, but I am very happy with the rest of the homebrew/pip package management, and know that this will add complication in the future. Nothing is available in the homebrew-versions tap.

Hoping there is a better option than screen sharing over vnc or restoring a backup.

Thanks for any advice.