# matplotlib is not working on google compute engine

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, google-compute-engine

I create a virtual server using compute engine. I can ssh through their ssh button. But when I run my code which has matplotlib it will not show the plot while I am not getting any error! here is my code for matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

when I run `echo $DISPLAY` it returns nothing and then I run `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` but still pyplot is not working. Is it possible to show it at all on GCE? or I am doing s.th wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: display plot on a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: The main point is that using the `"Agg"` backend, `plt.show()` has no effect and no plot is shown. This is what the `"Agg"` backend is made for: no GUI output. Whether you may actually get a graphical output using a different backend (`"TkAgg"`, `"GTK"`, `"PyQt4Agg"`, ...) may also depend on the server.