# How to use opencv in a remote jupyter notebook execution?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In my local machine with macOS Mojave, I installed a virtual environment with Python 3.6, opencv package and some additional unrelated packages.

I started a very simple Jupyter Notebook that is executed with no problem, here it's the code:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
my_img = cv2.imread("colibri_763_460.jpeg",1)
cv2.imshow("Original", my_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now, I'm trying to execute the same code in a Jupyter Notebook in my remote Ubuntu machine but I can't make it work. These are the steps that I took:

- I copied the image file and the Notebook ypnb file to the remote ubuntu machine.
- I opened an ssh session, selected a virtualenv with the same packages than my local machine and executed the "jupyter notebook"
- I opened another terminal with ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 mpastorg@mpgubu18 for the ssh tunneling
- I opened my local browser in the localhost:8000 to execute the Notebooks that I have in my remote Ubuntu machine, it works with any Notebook not involving opencv.

I tried to solve my problem using two different ways:

- Installing in the ubuntu remote machine the package opencv-contrib-python-headless: when I try to use *cv2.imshow*, I got the error method not found
- Installing in the ubuntu remote machine the package opencv-contrib-python: I got the error that kernel is dead.

Does anyone know if there's any way to execute the remote jupyter notebook and see the picture locally? it maybe would be possible a workaround to embed the picture in the browser window?

Thank you very much
Marcos Pastor

Comment: I had this problem in a Raspberry Pi. What if you try to use plt.imshow ? Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the image is being rendered using X - which you have not explicitly enabled, in both your host machine, nor in your ssh tunnel.

On the Host machine. (Where you want to see the Image).
Enter this comment

```
xhost+
```

This now allows remote X-Hosts to send you data. As you are on a Mac - you will need to have the **XQuartz** package installed.

Now modify your ssh command. - so that you allow X - this is typically done using a -X flag (Or it can be placed in your .ssh/config file like this

```
Host *
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted no
  XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
  ForwardAgent yes
  Compression yes
  KeepAlive yes
  Compression yes
```

If you are not using a config try the -X to start with.

Hope that helps