# if __name__ == '__main__' in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I have Python scripts that use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` trick to have some code only run when the script is called as a script and not when it is loaded into the interactive interpreter. However, when I edit these scripts from IPython using the `%edit` command, IPython apparently sets `__name__` to `'__main__'` and so the code gets run every time I exit the editing session. Is there a good way to make this code not run when the module is edited from IPython?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When working from within Emacs (which I assume is close to what you get with `%edit`), I usually use this trick:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and '__file__' in globals():
    # do what you need
```

For obvious reasons, `__file__` is defined only for `import`'ed modules, and not for interactive shell.

Comment: For those not aware that Jupyter notebooks were developed from IPython notebooks, I'll point out that the addition of the second part works in Jupyter notebooks so that the pertinent code block won't be run when pasted into the cell of a notebook. Also, those considering this may be interested in the approach featured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424821/8508004).

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you might just need the `-x` switch:

```
In [1]: %edit
IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_J8j9Wl.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
Name is main -- executing
Out[1]: "if __name__ == '__main__':\n    print 'Name is main -- executing'\n"

In [2]: %edit -x /tmp/ipython_edit_J8j9Wl
Editing...
```

When you call `%edit -x` the code is not executed after you exit your editor.

Comment: that `-x` switch is crucial.

Comment: Thanks; this is useful, but it doesn't quite do what I want because I want IPython to load the functions/classes defined in the module, just not run the test code associated with the module.

Comment: No problem. I thought you might have some clarification like this. I would personally recommend @ffriend's answer in light of this.

Answer (score 8):

IPython adds the function `get_ipython()` to the globally available variables. So you can test, whether this function exist in `globals()` to make your decision:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and "get_ipython" not in dir():
    print "I'm not loaded with IPython"
```

The above code just tests whether there is a global variable with name `get_ipython`. To also test whether this variable is callable, you can do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and not callable(globals().get("get_ipython", None)):
    print "I'm not loaded with IPython"
```

Answer (score 2):

IPython automatically executes the code you write with the `%edit` command. You can use `%edit -x` to specify that you do NOT want to run the code you were just editing.

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.code.html