# if __name__ == '__main__' not working ipython

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I'm having trouble getting the `if __name == '__main__'` trick to work in an IPython, Spyder environment. I've tried every approach given in this thread:
[if __name__ == '__main__' in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923002/if-name-main-in-ipython)

Here are my super simplified modules

Module1.py

```
Class UnitTest():
    print 'Mod1 UnitTest!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UnitTest()
```

Module2.py

```
import Module1

Class UnitTest():
    print 'Mod2 UnitTest!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UnitTest()
```

So I run Module2.py and I always am seeing both `Mod2 UnitTest` and `Mod1 UnitTest` printed.  These are executing in an IPython kernel.  I want only the `Mod2 UnitTest` message to display.

Any idea what's up?

Comment: You are using classes instead of functions.  Code in a class declaration is run at import time.

Comment: Yup.  See my answer below.  Totally foolish mistake not realizing the code in class declaration is run at import time!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I deleted this question earlier out of embarrassment but might as well share in case any other newb sees this.

I forgot to put the UnitTest line inside of the `__init__` method.  So the unit test was being run every single time when the class was defined and not when the object was instantiated.  The code should be:

Module1.py

```
Class UnitTest():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Mod1 UnitTest!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UnitTest()
```

Module2.py

```
import Module1

Class UnitTest():
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Mod1 UnitTest!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Mod2 UnitTest!'
```