# Why second `fit` call on `GridSearchCV` works endlessly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am adjusting hyperparameters in `Keras` model using `GridSearchCV` from `sklearn` as in [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/)

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

And they I call `fit` method to find the best hyperparameters

```
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
```

However, let's say that I want to change `batch_sizes` and call `fit` again (without restarting the kernel in Jupyter).

```
batch_size = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

And when I call `fit`

```
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
```

it works endlessly and won't terminate. In order to do the fit on this changed parameters I have to restart the kernel and then reload the data, modules, etc.

**Question.** How can I call `fit` second time on `GridSearchCV` without restarting the kernel?

---

**Details.** I use [this data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv). Detailed snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

dataset = np.loadtxt("data/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:8]
y = dataset[:,8]

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50]
param_grid = dict(batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

Then I call the `fit` and it works fine

```
grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Out: `Best: 0.690104 using {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 50}`

Then I run the following to make some changes:

```
batch_size = [5, 10, 15, 20]
param_grid = dict(batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
```

And finally I call the `fit` for the second time which never stops

```
grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: what dataset do you use? I am trying to confirm the problem right now. Do you use run the code in a notebook ?

Comment: @seralouk I paste the whole snnipet with details. Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @yes I have posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error on my MacBook Pro.
I used `pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv` dataset as well.

The issue here is with the tensorflow session. If a session is created in the parent process before `GridSearchCV.fit()`, it will hang for sure.

One possible solution would be to keep all session creation code restricted to the `KerasClassifer` class and the model creation function.

Additionally, you may want to restrict the memory usage of TF in either the model creation function or a subclass of `KerasClassifier`.

---

**Fast solution:**

```
n_jobs = 1
```

but it will take a long time to finish.

---

**References:**

[Session hang issue with python multiprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8220#issuecomment-370126516)

[Keras + Tensorflow and Multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504669/keras-tensorflow-and-multiprocessing-in-python/42506478#42506478)

[Limit the resource usage for tensorflow backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1538)

[GridSearchCV Hangs On Second Run](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10538)

[scikit-lean GridSearchCV n_jobs != 1 freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918220/5025009)

Comment: Fast solution worked, but I will yet try to load `keras` modules inside function `create_model`

Comment: Yes, another thing to try is to use `if __name__ == '__main__'` if you use Winsdows. let me know and please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I am ussing Google Compute VM with Debian. I will browse through links you have provided and try to find the best solution for me. `n_jobs =  1` is a poor solution because my VM provides multiple CPUs

Comment: I tried to wrap the code inside the function (and functions) and import `keras` module inside, but I see that I do it mindlessly and nothing works. I guess from your note *One possible solution would be to keep all session creation code restricted to the KerasClassifer class and the model creation function.* and from the post from the first link of yours, that it is possible somehow. Can you give me some hints how to do it?