# Determine if we're in an IPython notebook session

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want my function to do one thing if it's called from the IPython notebook and another thing if its called from a console or library code.  In particular I'm making a progress bar with the desired following behavior:

- **Notebook**: Immediately return a widget
- **Console**:  Block and dump information to `sys.stdout`

Is there a flag somewhere I can check to determine if the user called my function from a notebook or otherwise?

Comment: Would the second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook) serve your purposes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't detect that the frontend *is a notebook* with perfect precision, because an IPython Kernel can have one or more different Jupyter frontends with different capabilities (terminal console, qtconsole, notebook, etc.). You can, however, identify that it is a Kernel and not plain terminal IPython:

```
import sys

def is_kernel():
    if 'IPython' not in sys.modules:
        # IPython hasn't been imported, definitely not
        return False
    from IPython import get_ipython
    # check for `kernel` attribute on the IPython instance
    return getattr(get_ipython(), 'kernel', None) is not None
```

Since the notebook is so much more popular than other frontends, this indicates that the frontend is **probably** a notebook, but not conclusively. So you want to be sure there's a way out for the more primitive frontends.