# tqdm variations in different python enviroments

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, spyder, tqdm

I'm working with `tqdm` package that presents progress bar in python.

tqdm has also a widget for Jupyter notebooks (`tqdm_notebook()`), allowing a pretty "web-ish" progress bar.

My problem that I have a tqdm progress bar inside a `code.py` file, that I import into jupyter notebook.

While running the `code.py` from regular python eviroment (i.e. `Ipython`, `IDLE`, `shell`) I want tqdm to run in normal form:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
a = 0
for i in tqdm(range(2000)):
   a+=i
```

but when I import `code.py` into Jupyter, I want it to use `tqdm_notebook()`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
a = 0
for i in tqdm(range(2000)):
   a+=i
```

**How can I make python distinguish between the environments?**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412661/3861108) that suggest to check `get_ipython().__class__.__name__` or `'ipykernel' in sys.modules`
 but it doesn't distinguish between the notebook and other Ipython shells (such as in Spyder or IDLE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, using `sys.argv` can help here.

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Running this code in `Jupyter` will have this arguments:

```
['C:\\Users\\...\\lib\\site-packages\\ipykernel\\__main__.py',
 '-f',
 'C:\\Users\\...\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-###.json']
```

While of course running from shell/IDLE won't have the `jupyter` line.

Therefore the import statement in `code.py` should be:

```
if any('jupyter' in arg for arg in sys.argv):
    from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
else:
   from tqdm import tqdm
```

Answer (score 5):

`tqdm` now has an `autonotebook` module. From the [doc](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#ipython-jupyter-integration):

It is possible to let tqdm automatically choose between console or notebook versions by using the autonotebook submodule:

```py
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
```

Note that this will issue a `TqdmExperimentalWarning` if run in a notebook since it is not meant to be possible to distinguish between jupyter notebook and jupyter console. **Use auto instead of autonotebook to suppress this warning.**