# Python tqdm import check if jupyter notebook or lab is running

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a module (tqdm) that I need to import differently depending on whether I'm running my `.ipynb` in a jupyter notebook or jupyter lab environment. Is there way that I can determine this in python? For example:

```
if <jupyter notebook>:
    from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm 
elif <jupyter lab>:
    from tqdm import tqdm
else:
    print("Not in jupyter environment.")
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24937408/6646912 and https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/443

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
# either:
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
# or to suppress the warning:
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
```

For other modules/checks, see [How can I check if code is executed in the IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook/) (But note that the accepted albeit unpopular answer there is "this is intentionally not meant to be possible by design.")

Comment: This only says, how to import tqdm, not how to detect jupyter!

Comment: The OP is specifically about `tqdm`. If you want a more generic test, there's a different answer linked in a comment on the OP

Comment: The OP gives tqdm as an example. Should this post be re-titled "How to import tqdm in Jupyter"? Because now it turns up in wrong search results. Instead of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook/

Comment: Hmm yes looks like it.

Comment: Updated title & answer