# Can Python tell whether it is being executed in JupyterLab vs Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When Python code is called from a notebook, is it possible to determine whether the notebook is the old notebook vs JupyterLab?

The context behind the question is that I want to display some Javascript-enabled content inline inside the notebook. For regular notebooks, I have all kinds of goodies available (require.js, ability to execute scripts, access to `Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute`, etc). In JupyterLab, all of those have been removed for the sake of security.

I'm not questioning the change in JupyterLab, but I do need to determine if those "Javascript goodies" are available or not. If they are not, I will write a temporary html page and open a webbrowser pointing to it -- not quite as nice, but it will do until I decide to write a lab extension and users decide to install it.

So, **how do I tell if I'm running within a regular notebook vs lab?**

The challenges I run into with potential solutions are:

1. Anything I execute in Javascript using `display(Javascript(...))` is run asynchronously after my Python code returns. So I can't simply write `if call_javascript() == 'notebook'` or something.
2. If I allow for the asynchronous nature of Javascript and pass a callback, that only works for the plain notebook. There is no way for JupyterLab to call me back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python check if jupyter notebook or lab is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915913/python-check-if-jupyter-notebook-or-lab-is-running)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney That link does attempt to answer the same question I have. The answers, unfortunately, appear to only work on older versions of IPython.