# Is there a way to detect that notebook is displayed in voila, jupyter or jupyterlab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, voila

I'm using the [xarray_leaflet](https://github.com/davidbrochart/xarray_leaflet) library that has has a different behavior if the notebook is launch with voila, jupyter or jupyterLab.

Is there a way to detect it programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

In versions of voila > `.2`, there are a bunch of environmental variables on the running environment (e.g. `'QUERY_STRING', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'SERVER_PORT', 'PATH_INFO', 'SERVER_NAME', 'SCRIPT_NAME'`), so detecting if you are running in voila is as simple as checking if any of those exist, or even better:

```
import os
running_in_voila = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','jupyter').startswith('voila')
```