# Get Jupyter notebook URL without using IPython.notebook.kernel.execute

Tags: python, url, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to access the current URL of a Jupyter notebook including parameters, however I'm operating in a custom environment that has disabled direct access to IPython from javascript so I can't use IPython.notebook.kernel.execute.  AFAIK all other communication works fine, input widgets still work etc.

Is there a way to retrieve the current URL of the running notebook in Python that doesn't use IPython.notebook.kernel.execute?

Comment: Some of the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498256/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478944/8508004) get you what you need?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne, I’ve consulted with our engineers and looks like a similar case the links you posted Ie one way is to have a custom widget, but on our custom environment that wears a hefty engineering overhead.  Was hoping for a “in notebook” solution

Comment: Even if there a way now going forward, your solution may not be an option beyond your custom environment. A lot of the older abilities will be not as accessible as the underlying machinery becomes more complex and more like JupyterLab where things need to be integrated as good citizens to play well in the ecosystem. See [Build Jupyter Notebook v7 off of JupyterLab components](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). Does the Real time collaboration route maybe allow options?