# Detecting if ipython notebook is outputting to a terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to detect if a Jupyter Notebook is being executed in a terminal e.g. via `ipython --TerminalIPythonApp.file_to_run` command, as opposite to a HTML enabled notebook. Note that this is different from detecting if the Python code is run with `python` or within a notebook.

Based on this I can format Pandas DataFrames suitable either for HTML or for terminal display.

How can I detect if a notebook is outputting to a terminal?

Comment: Could you accept the below as an answer please if that works for you? Thanks.

Comment: Hi William! Sorry, I did not manage to find out time to try the answer yet, but you will definitely get the checkmark. I hope to test it out and leave some feedback before accepting. The bounty is still running for 3 days.

Comment: Thanks Mikko. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```
from IPython import get_ipython
def type_of_execution():
    try:
        type_of_exec = str(type(get_ipython()))
        if 'terminal' in type_of_exec:
            return 'terminal'
        elif 'zmqshell' in type_of_exec:
            return 'jupyter'
        else:
            return 'python'
    except:
        return 'terminal likely'
print("Checking..")
print(type_of_execution())
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on William's answer I figured this out.

Terminal output example:

[image]

HTML output example:

[image]

Here is some sample code, cleaned up from William's answer and also some more context how this can be utilised.

[See an example quantitative finance notebook using this](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/algorithms/pancakeswap-momentum-liquidity-aware.html#Analyzing-the-strategy-results). [See full source code](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/client/blob/master/tradingstrategy/utils/jupyter.py).

```py
"""Helpers to deal with Jupyter Notebook issues."""
import enum
from typing import Callable

import pandas as pd
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
from ipykernel.zmqshell import ZMQInteractiveShell


class JupyterOutputMode(enum.Enum):
    """What kind of output Jupyter Notebook supports."""

    #: We could not figure out - please debug
    unknown = "unknown"

    #: The notebook is run by terminal
    terminal = "terminal"

    #: Your normal HTML notebook
    html = "html"


def get_notebook_execution_mode() -> JupyterOutputMode:
    """Determine if the Jupyter Notebook supports HTML output."""

    # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768390/detecting-if-ipython-notebook-is-outputting-to-a-terminal
    # for discussion
    ipython = get_ipython()

    if isinstance(ipython, TerminalInteractiveShell):
        # Hello ANSI graphics my old friend
        return JupyterOutputMode.terminal
    elif isinstance(ipython, ZMQInteractiveShell):
        # MAke an assumption ZMQ instance is a HTML notebook
        return JupyterOutputMode.html

    return JupyterOutputMode.unknown


def display_with_styles(df: pd.DataFrame, apply_styles_func: Callable):
    """Display a Pandas dataframe as a table.

    DataFrame styler objects only support HTML output.
    If the Jupyter Notebook output does not have HTML support,
    (it is a command line), then display DataFrame as is
    without styles.

    For `apply_style_func` example see :py:method:`tradingstrategy.analysis.portfolioanalyzer.expand_timeline`.

    :param df: Pandas Dataframe we want to display as a table.

    :param apply_styles_func: A function to call on DataFrame to add its styles on it.
        We need to pass this as callable due to Pandas architectural limitations.
        The function will create styles using `pandas.DataFrame.style` object.
        However if styles are applied the resulting object can no longer be displayed in a terminal.
        Thus, we need to separate the procses of creating dataframe and creating styles and applying them.

    """
    mode = get_notebook_execution_mode()
    if mode == JupyterOutputMode.html:
        display(apply_styles_func(df))
    else:
        display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answers so far are similar to the ones on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook), namely trying to divine runtime features from incidentals such as `get_ipython()` being defined or returning an instance of a certain class. Those tests will always be brittle and [probably also wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412661) because there are many variations of notebook runtimes, such as Jupyter, JupyterLab, and Google Colab, and the tests only provide indirect evidence for HTML support.

Reading [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412661) (which is the same as the previous link) made me realize that there is a more direct and robust way: Try to display something and see what format the runtime picks.

To turn that idea into code, here's a small helper class. It can be displayed as either HTML or plain text. It also records the runtime's choice.

```py
class DisplayInspector:
    """Objects that display as HTML or text."""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.status = None

    def _repr_html_(self) -> str:
        self.status = 'HTML'
        return '<p>Checking HTML support: ✅</p>'

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        self.status = 'Plain'
        return 'Checking HTML support: ❌'
```

We also need a function to actually conduct the experiment:

```py
import sys

def supports_html() -> bool:
    """Test whether current runtime supports HTML."""
    if (
        'IPython' not in sys.modules
        or 'IPython.display' not in sys.modules
    ):
        return False

    from IPython.display import display
    inspector = DisplayInspector()
    display(inspector)
    return inspector.status == 'HTML'
```

That's it. By design, this test leaves a visible trace. That's a good thing: It makes the test more robust because it actually tests what we want to know. That's also a bad thing: It leaves a visible trace. If that bugs you, I would recommend returning empty strings from both methods. At least, that worked for me.