# Determine if Code is Running on Databricks or IDE (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, databricks

I am in the process of building a Python package that can be used by Data Scientists to manage their MLOps lifecycle. Now, this package can be used either locally (usually on PyCharm) or on Databricks.

I want a certain functionality of the package to be dependent on where it is running, i.e. I want it to do something different if it is called by a Databricks notebook and something else entirely if it is running locally.

Is there any way I can determine where it is being called from?

I am a little doubtful as to whether we can use something like the following that checks if your code is running on a notebook or otherwise since this will be a package that is going to be stored in your Databricks environment,

[How can I check if code is executed in the IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround I've found to work is to check for databricks specific environment variables.

```
import os
def is_running_in_databricks() -> bool:
    return "DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION" in os.environ
```