# RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I am running my python script in another machine by using `ssh` command in `linux`. I have also run this command :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

after logging in the other machine, in order to define the proper paths in the new machine. I was getting the error message for running the following python code lines even I have tried to follow the instruction in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321292/using-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) by defining the backend.

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import pylab as plt
>>> matplotlib.use('Agg')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.arange(0,2,0.001)
>>> y=np.sin(x)**2+4*np.cos(x)
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> plt.plot(x,y,'r.')
```

The error message

```
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Systematic_Optimised.py", line 513, in <module>
    fig = plt.figure()
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 47, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 54, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 72, in __init__
    FigureCanvasQT.__init__(self, figure)
  File "/vol/aibn84/data2/zahra/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py", line 68, in __init__
    _create_qApp()
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 138, in _create_qApp
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

any suggestion how to fix the problem

Comment: Do `echo $DISPLAY` on your machine. What is your OS, are you running over ssh?

Comment: If you have to use the display on the remote machine, you need to use ssh with the `-X` argument.

Comment: @KlausD. I have used `ssh -X username@host` command to login.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You must declare `matplotlib.use('agg')` before `import pylab as plt`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706614/841339)

Comment: still I have the runtime error :( 
File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 138, in _create_qApp
raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable

Comment: Take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3466/#issuecomment-195899517)

Comment: it seems you should use lower case 'a', so do matplotlib.use('agg') before import pylab as plt.

Comment: @MichelleOwen have you tested? I cannot test it now!

Comment: @MauroBaraldi yes, I did. At least it worked for me.

Comment: worked for me too in a virtual environment after having to `pip install PySide`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('agg')` didn't fix the error, but `import matplotlib; matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('agg')` did (as suggested [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3466/#issuecomment-270603717)).

Answer (score 56):

Add

```
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

after

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks! This plays much more nicely with pylint :)

Comment: This is fantastic, now I can switch the backends depending on how I run the code. I have a problem when using 'agg' which stops showing the plot in the command window which can sometimes be disappointing. Therefore, I can switch out the backend for my uses.