# docker/matplotlib: RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, docker

I tried lots of solving method, none of them worked.

I tried `echo $DISPLAY` not working

Error Message:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://10.231.xx.xx:8000/upload/
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/code/fileUpload_app/views.py" in msa_result
>     174.     result1 = generate_hist(db, **processing_dict)
>
> File "/code/fileUpload_app/post_processing.py" in generate_hist
>     182.         fig1 = plt.figure()
>
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py" in
>   figure
>     527.                                         **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py"
>   in new_figure_manager
>     46.     return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py"
>   in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>     53.     canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py"
>   in **init**
>     76.         FigureCanvasQT.**init**(self, figure)
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py"
>   in **init**
>     68.         _create_qApp()
>
> File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py"
>   in _create_qApp
>     138.                     raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
>
> Exception Type: RuntimeError at /upload/msa_result/1/ Exception Value:
>   Invalid DISPLAY variable

I am using a docker to host my web project.

My code includes these :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_hist(db, **kwargs):


    fig1 = plt.figure()

    hist = mat2[0, 0:pin_num]

    fig1 = plt.hist(hist)

    plt.savefig("fileUpload_app/static/img/result/hist.jpg")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "echo $DISPLAY" not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that I `import seaborn` before I `import matplotlib`. This caused matplotlib not running in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

From here: [RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737116/runtimeerror-invalid-display-variable)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

I used this on a remote machine, with ssh & screen, no X forwarding.