# Pandas Plot: Suppress Plot output to allow running Script in Bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cron

I have a python script I want to run via a cronjob, it would create several plots based on some data and save them to a directory on my server. I'm using `pandas.plot`. The script runs fine on my local machine, and also using a python notebook on the server. However, when running in the terminal with `$ python myscript.py` I get:

```
raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

A similar matplotlib question (not helpful as it's specific to MPL): [RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737116/runtimeerror-invalid-display-variable). Here the solution seems to route the console output somewhere else.

```
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

or

```
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

I'm assuming that the error is related to there being no "display" for the plot to show on. In my script I have the plot being assigned to a variable, yet I can't seem to prevent it printing to console.

```
for query_metadata, dataframe in query_results.items():

    df = dataframe

    df.reset_index(inplace = True)

    fig = df.plot.area(xticks=df.index, rot = 90, figsize = (20,8))
    fig.set_xticklabels(df['date1'])
    fig.set_title(key)
    fig_ext = fig.get_figure()

    fig_ext.savefig("{0}/{1}.png".format(save_dir, key))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the solution, just set the backend right before importing pandas:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import pandas as pd
...
```