# matplotlib pyplot Invalid DISPLAY variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

While importing and attempting the following:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
plt.show()
```

I get the following error. How do I fix? I am running Python 2.7, and notebook version 4.1.0. Thank you.

```
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

Comment: it's possible that you're using it with a different users from the one that is running the X subsystem. Try using the same user. Otherwise, as a quick workaround and provided that you have a single display, try this before running your script: **export DISPLAY=:0**

Comment: Do you by chance run the Python remotely on another computer via SSH?

Comment: export DISPLAY=:0 gives invalid syntax. Is it =:0? Thank you.

Comment: The jupyter notebook reside on linux server and I am using the chrome browser to work in the notebooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a jupyter notebook on a server, the server may not even be able to display the plot. The [usual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321292/using-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) would be to use a non-interactive backend. In case of a jupyter notebook this would be done by adding

```
%matplotlib inline
```

at the top of the notebook, such that graphics are shown as png images.