# _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable (via ssh)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

I am trying to create a plot on a remote machine using `pyplot` and I get the following exception `_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`. Before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I do

`import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')`

However, it does not solve the issue. The exception is thrown when `fig = plt.figure()` is being executed. Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

PS. I access the remote machine via `ssh -X ...`.

Comment: There are several questions with similar titles listed under **Related** - anything that might help you?

Comment: Same error with e.g. this example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706451/how-to-save-a-figure-remotely-with-pylab/4706614#4706614

Comment: Like I said, I've done all of those steps, and still get that error.