# Generating matplotlib graphs without a running X server

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib seems to require the $DISPLAY environment variable which means a running X server.
Some web hosting services do not allow a running X server session.
Is there a way to generate graphs using matplotlib without a running X server?

```
[username@hostname ~]$ python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Nov 23 2010, 02:02:03)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/lib/python2.6/matplotlib-1.0.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 270, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/lib/python2.6/matplotlib-1.0.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1643, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
>>>
```

Answer (score 360, accepted):

@Neil's answer is one (perfectly valid!) way of doing it, but you can also [simply call `matplotlib.use('Agg')` *before* importing `matplotlib.pyplot`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server), and then continue as normal.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
fig.savefig('temp.png')
```

You don't have to use the Agg backend, as well.  The [pdf, ps, svg, agg, cairo, and gdk backends](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) can all be used without an X-server.  However, only the Agg backend will be built by default (I think?), so there's a good chance that the other backends may not be enabled on your particular install.

Alternately, you can just set the backend parameter in your [`.matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) file to automatically have `matplotlib.pyplot` use the given renderer.

Comment: It seems insane to me that you have to import matplotlib twice. Is there an easier way?

Comment: For what it's worth, you're not actually importing matplotlib twice.  You're importing matplotlib and then importing a sub-module that's not automatically imported.  There are other ways, yes (for example, change your `.maplotlibrc` file), that that's the most straight-forward one.

Comment: what if I already imported pyplot ? can I still do it ?

Comment: It stated "matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time."

Comment: Most backends you mentioned (specifically: pdf, ps, svg, agg)  are non-GUI backends, so they do not allow to show the plot directly from the code.

Comment: this is incredibly simple and worked perfectly on WSL. thanks a lot.

Comment: More specifically for the latter alternative, under Linux you just need to save `backend: Agg` in the file `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

Comment: I can easily do `mpl.use("Agg")` *after* importing any of the mentioned dependent packages, it just needs to be before *using* them.

Answer (score 22):

You need to use the matplotlib API directly rather than going through the pylab interface. There's a good example here:

http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/23/matplotlib_without_gui.html

Comment: I'm working with `ssh` and `screen` and besides the `matplotlib.use('Agg')`suggestion this was the only solution that worked. Thanks for the contribution

Comment: @user3085931: Nice to know my answer's still useful to someone 5 years after I wrote it! Thanks for letting me know.