# Tkinter: "Python may not be configured for Tk"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Today I wanted to start working with Tkinter, but I have some problems.

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Mar 28 2011, 04:14:07) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tkinter import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

So how can I configure my Python 3.2 to work with Tkinter?

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, if you're looking to use the latest Python on Linux, using pre-compiled binaries (such as ActivePython - which includes Tkinter) would save a lot of time.

Comment: Every Linux distribution ever has an official python package. Unless you need something specific, using 3rd party binaries is actually discouraged. That said, you are probably one or two commands from having Tk support in python, but I need to know what flavor of Linux you are running.

Comment: I think the most complete answer to this is here: [How to get tkinter working with Ubuntu's default Python 2.7 install?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11799470/5402386)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter :

> If it fails with "No module named _tkinter", your Python configuration needs to be modified to include this module (which is an extension module implemented in C). Do **not** edit Modules/Setup (it is out of date). You may have to install Tcl and Tk (when using RPM, install the -devel RPMs as well) and/or edit the setup.py script to point to the right locations where Tcl/Tk is installed. If you install Tcl/Tk in the default locations, simply rerunning "make" should build the _tkinter extension.

Comment: How do you edit the setup.py script? How do you rerun make? I'm trying to do this on a mac and I'm finding that I should just return the mac and get a windows machine.

Comment: In my case this was caused by an upgrade of `tk`. It was only used by `matplotlib`, and that can be circumnavigated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935945/1959808

Comment: the setup.py is located in source code directory of python

Comment: I have roughly 50 setup.py files in my computer, which is the right one?

Comment: Simply installing the `tk` package fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 148):

## Solution for Linux, Windows (WSL/Ubuntu) and MacOS

After trying a bunch of things, this is how it finally worked:

```
$ brew install python-tk
```

Comment: The brew install worked for me on Catalina

Comment: The pip3 package `tk` is TensorKit, see [here](https://pypi.org/project/tk/). I don't think this helps.

Comment: brew install from my macOS terminal did the work, once I got back to Pycharm the 'no module' error was gone.

Comment: Good lord, thanks. I was trying a lot of things and finally, this made it work.

Comment: Brew isn't a "MacOS" thing. It's supported by Linux (including in WSL/Windows 10) as well as MacOS. In fact, the Linuxbrew project has been merged entirely into HomeBrew, so yeah; definately not a "MacOS" thing.

Comment: @rainabba but no self respecting linux user would use brew when there's asdf or the package manager available for the OS.... i mean you can't even pin a package to a version with brew....

Comment: every time I use brew install I want to get a hammer and disassemble the laptop. I can't believe that it always downloads 300 other things along the way, and `pouring` forever :rofl:
I mean, why in heavens name would it download `php` if you want to get python-tk???

Comment: You can also use something like `brew install python-tk@3.9` if you require a specific version of python

Answer (score 129):

Under Arch/Manjaro just install the package `tk`:

```
sudo pacman -S tk
```

Answer (score 61):

Install `tk-devel` (or a similarly-named package) before building Python.

Comment: On Ubuntu run 'sudo apt-get install tk-dev', and then re-run make

Comment: @pycoder112358: I did it but it's still telling me `ImportError: No module named _tkinter` when I try to import tkinter. I use python3.4.0 compiled from source on ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: What's `tk-devel`
? You should give at least a minimal explanation of why it should be useful in this case.

Comment: As a comment to others, the "before building Python" is important here. When you install the module you need to rebuild python before it'll find the module.

Comment: This is the correct solution when installing Python from source on a Linux system.

Comment: I am installing Python via `asdf`, and I have installed `tk-dev` on Ubuntu, and I am still getting this error.

Comment: I deleted my python 3.12.0, installed tk-dev, downloaded python 3.12.2 and then built from source 3.12.2 and I still cannot import tkinter (ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 56):

To get this to work with `pyenv` on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, I had to:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

Then install the version of Python I wanted:

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.2
```

Then I could import tkinter just fine:

```
import tkinter
```

Comment: And for MacOS X all you need is `brew install python-tk`.

Comment: Intuitively I'd think that you would only need to install the `tk-dev` package for this to work, but I haven't tested it so I'm not sure.

Comment: @AviNerenberg your intuition was right. I had to install only `tk-dev` to make it work.

Answer (score 9):

So appearantly many seems to have had this issue (me including) and I found the fault to be that Tkinter wasn't installed on my system when python was compiled.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357567/cannot-import-tkinter-after-installing-python-3-with-pyenv) describes how to solve the problem by:

1. Removing the virtual environment/python distribution
2. install Tkinter with `sudo apt-get install tk-dev` (for deb) or `sudo pacman -S tk` (for arch/manjaro)
3. Then proceed to compile python again.

This worked wonders for me.

Comment: This is the right solution, thanks! I still don't know why the most upvoted answers make you go through a lot of hoops without explaining how to do it even and a simple command line is buried at the bottom...

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Hope that someone else might find this more useful than all the guesswork that has been done is this thread :/

Answer (score 7):

since I can not comment yet, here's my answer to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73678463/4735924):

since I'm still using python 3.9, this code works for me:

```
brew install python-tk@3.9
```

if using `brew install python-tk` brew will install python-tk@3.10 which is key-only

Comment: this finally worked!

Answer (score 5):

I also faced similar problem. I resolved it by installing `python-tk` in my system.

Command for mac : `brew install python-tk`.

Answer (score 5):

if you're managing python with https://asdf-vm.com/ on linux, then :

Fedora

```bash
$ asdf uninstall python 3.10.10
$ sudo dnf install tk-devel
$ asdf install  python 3.10.10
```

Ubuntu

```bash
$ asdf uninstall python 3.10.10
$ sudo apt-get install tk-dev
$ asdf install  python 3.10.10
```

Macos

```
$ asdf uninstall python 3.10.10
$ brew install python-tk
$ asdf install  python 3.10.10
```

This is because installing python with asdf will cause it to compile parts of the python core. If certain things aren't present at the time then they don't get included/enabled.
So you need to make those things present and remove and install python again.

- https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-python/issues/121#issuecomment-1279537646

Comment: This is what worked for me on macOS as I was also managing my pythons via asdf. Thank you!

Comment: This is what fixed my issue on Ubuntu. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue on Fedora with Python 2.7. Turns out some extra packages are required:

```
sudo dnf install tk-devel tkinter
```

After installing the packages, this [hello-world](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm) example seems to be working fine on Python 2.7:

```
$ cat hello.py
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
$ python hello.py
```

And through X11 forwarding, it looks like this:

[image: Hello World through X11]

Note that in Python 3, the module name is lowercase, and other packages are probably required...

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: sudo: dnf: command not found (I'm ubuntu, is this the difference?)

Answer (score 4):

Oh I just have followed the solution Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has suggest which is install tk-dev before building the python.
(Building the Python-3.6.1 from source on Ubuntu 16.04.)

There was pre-compiled objects and binaries I have had build yesterday though, I didn't clean up the objects and just build again on the same build path. And it works beautifully.

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
(On the python build path)
(No need to conduct 'make clean')
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 3):

## Installing Tkinter

---

```sh
python -m pip install tk-tools
```

##### or

```sh
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

## Code

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('My App')
# Code
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue on python 2.7.9.
To fix it, I installed tk and tcl, and then rebuild python code and reinstall, and during configure, I set the path for tk and tcl explicitly, by:

```
./configure --with-tcltk-includes="-I/usr/include" --with-tcltk-libs="-L/usr/lib64 -ltcl8.5 -L/usr/lib64 -ltk8.5"
```

Also, a whole article for python install process: [Building Python from Source](http://notmatthancock.github.io/2015/06/17/building-python-from-source.html)

Answer (score 2):

now i figured out what's going on ubuntu,

Follow these step to solve the issue

1. check your python version `python3 --version`
2. Lets Imagine you have python 3.10
3. Then Install Python-tk for the python version by using bellow command
4. `sudo apt install python3.10-tk`

simple if you have python3.8 then `sudo apt install python{"use your python version here"}-tk`

Comment: `apt install python3.7-tk`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.7-tk
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7-tk'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7-tk'

Answer (score 1):

I think the most complete answer to this is the accepted answer found here:

[How to get tkinter working with Ubuntu's default Python 2.7 install?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11799470/5402386)

> I figured it out after way too much time spent on this problem, so
>   hopefully I can save someone else the hassle.
>
> I found this old bug report deemed invalid that mentioned the exact
>   problem I was having, I had Tkinter.py, but it couldn't find the
>   module _tkinter: http://bugs.python.org/issue8555
>
> I installed the tk-dev package with apt-get, and rebuilt Python using
>   ./configure, make, and make install in the Python2.7.3 directory. And
>   now my Python2.7 can import Tkinter, yay!
>
> I'm a little miffed that the tk-dev package isn't mentioned at all in
>   the Python installation documentation.... below is another helpful
>   resource on missing modules in Python if, like me, someone should
>   discover they are missing more than _tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone using Windows and Windows Subsystem for Linux, make sure that when you run the python command from the command line, it's not accidentally running the python installation from WSL! This gave me quite a headache just now. A quick check you can do for this is just
`which <python command you're using>`
If that prints something like `/usr/bin/python2` even though you're in powershell, that's probably what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on an AWS instance that is running Amazon Linux OS, the magic command to fix this for me was

```
sudo yum install tkinter
```

If you want to determine your Linux build, try `cat /etc/*release`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Manjaro**(Arch Linux) run below command in your terminal

```
sudo pacman -S tk
```

Answer (score 0):

This symptom can also occur when a later version of python (2.7.13, for example) has been installed in /usr/local/bin "alongside of" the release python version, and then a subsequent operating system upgrade (say, Ubuntu 12.04 --> Ubuntu 14.04) fails to remove the updated python there.

To fix that imcompatibility, one must

a) remove the updated version of python in /usr/local/bin;

b) uninstall python-idle2.7; and

c) reinstall python-idle2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing python-tk, python3-tk I was getting error your python is not configured for Tk.

So I additionally installed tk8.6-dev
Then I build my Python again, run following again:
make,
make install.

When I did this I saw messages on screen that it is building _tkinter and related modules. Once that is done, I tried 'import tkinter"  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, pyenv was installed but I was not aware of it. I needed to uninstall and reinstall the python version via pyenv to fix the tkinter configuration after installing the right version of `python3.x-tk`.