# Cannot import tkinter after installing Python 3 with pyenv

Tags: python

I got problems with importing `tkinter` after installing Python version 3.4.2 with `pyenv`. My system Python is version 2.7.6. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. For the following sample script `t.py`:

```
import _tkinter

print ("Hello")
```

I get:

```
$ pyenv global system
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python t.py
Hello
$ pyenv global 3.4.2
$ python --version
Python 3.4.2
$ python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "t.py", line 3, in <module>
        import _tkinter
    ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Note that `pyenv` installed Python version 3.4.2 in `~/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/`.

Comment: Don't import private modules unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @simonzack Is `tkinter` a private module?

Comment: In this case yes, names prefixed with `_` mean private as a convention.

Comment: I just followed the instructions at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter .. It says you should first try to import `_tkinter`.. and importing `tkinter` without underscore does not work either..

Comment: That's for testing the install.

Comment: Ok, but I get the same error when importing `tkinter`..

Comment: You probably didn't use pyenv correctly then. Hard to tell why though, maybe try this without pyenv?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This problem seems to be solved now using the approach described in this [post](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/94):

- First uninstall Python 3.4.2 : `pyenv uninstall 3.4.2`, then
- Run  `sudo apt-get install tk-dev`
- And reinstall Python 3.4.2 : `pyenv install 3.4.2`

Comment: In Centos, you have to install `tkinter` using this command:
`sudo yum install python34-tk*`

Comment: Awesome! No need to set env variables!

Comment: This worked for me although I don't understand why I have to uninstall python and then install tk and then reinstall

Comment: on Arch, this procedure with `sudo pacman -S tk` did the trick for me (Python 3.9.12 via pyenv).

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS you can try installing `tcl-tk` via homebrew and then activating the env. vars. mentioned in its caveats section, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469203/39396).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
import tkinter
```

Documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html):

> Most of the time, tkinter is all you really need, but a number of additional modules are available as well. The Tk interface is located in a binary module named _tkinter. This module contains the low-level interface to Tk, and should never be used directly by application programmers. It is usually a shared library (or DLL), but might in some cases be statically linked with the Python interpreter.

Comment: It still does not work. See step 1 at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter . It says you should first try to import `_tkinter`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland That's for testing the install.

Comment: @simonzack Yes that was exactly what I was trying to do.. testing the install.. I never use `import _tkinter` in my regular code..