# Installing tkinter on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run python code on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I execute it, it gives me the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Answer (score 72):

Try writing the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Don't forget to actually import Tkinter module at the beginning of your program:

```
import Tkinter
```

Comment: Similarly, you can do sudo apt-get install python3-tk for the python3 version.

Comment: How to install it using requirements.txt file ?

Answer (score 46):

If you're using `Python 3` then you must install as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Tkinter for `Python 2` (`python-tk`) is different from `Python 3`'s (`python3-tk`).

Answer (score 16):

To get this to work with `pyenv` on Ubuntu 16.04, I had to:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

Then install the version of Python I wanted via `pyenv`:

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.2
```

Then I could import tkinter just fine:

```
import tkinter
```

Comment: What is pyenv? My system can't find it.

Comment: @sureshvv pyenv is a Python version management tool: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: Python version isn't the deciding factor. Having installed `$ sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev` before installing python is deciding factor here. As suggested in another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358646/953338

Comment: I just used sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev and it worked

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have Tkinter module installed.

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

In python 2 the package name is Tkinter not tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
```

ref: http://www.techinfected.net/2015/09/how-to-install-and-use-tkinter-in-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint.html

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
```

If you're using python3, then Python3 virtual environment(venv) is also required. Use:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `python-tk` like

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

That is described (with `apt-cache search python-tk` as)

```
Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS:

1. Go to Software Center and remove "IDLE(using Python-2.7)".
2. Install "IDLE(using Python-3.4)".

Try again.  This step worked for me.