# Tk not defined in tkinter ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tkinter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 lts. It keep saying me that tk is not defined . Is there a way to install tkinter in Ubuntu . Pls help me

Comment: *It keep saying me that tk is not defined*.Please share the code that triggered this error by editing your question

Comment: I see 75 questions on stackoverflow when I search for "install tkinter ubuntu". Did absolutely none of those help  you?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702119/installing-tkinter-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm able to get the output in python3 idle but not in pycharm

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I'm able to get the output in python3 idle but not in pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then depending on your version of Python run one of the following below:

Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: I'm using pycharm buy I'm not able to get the output . It still says error but I'm able to get the output in python3 idle