# python - importing turtle module

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever I import `turtle`, I get this error

```
>>> import turtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import Tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

What do I do to get the `turtle` module?

Comment: We're going to need quite a bit more information. You're evidently running on a Unix-based system; which one? How did you install Python?

Comment: This part of the error looks relevant: "If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk". Looks like your Python may not be configured for Tk.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk).