# "UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to plot a simple graph using pyplot, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,7,4])
plt.show()
```

but the figure does not appear and I get the following message:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

I found and tried some advice to re-configure the "backend" mentioned in that warning, like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but this gives me an error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

I assumed that I had to install this module separately, but `pip install tkinter` does not work:

```
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

How can I make Matplotlib display the graph?

---

<sub>**See also**: [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218) . This question is not a duplicate, because the answers discuss other backends besides the Tkinter one.</sub>

<sub>Also see [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289) for issues with attempts to use Matplotlib remotely.</sub>

Comment: Are you actually using tkinter for anything, or did you just pick it as a plt backend?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thank you for the hint. I will indeed focus on installing tkinter first. I will have a look at the link you provided and see if I can make anything out of it.

Comment: @G.Anderson: I had no idea what tkinter was before I ran into this error with matplotlib. Now I am trying to install it just to be able to show graphs (so yes, I guess I just picked it as a plt backend). If you know of any other way (i.e. without using tkinter), I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: There are [a number of backends](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/index_backend_api.html) you can use. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015816/7835267) is an answer about cycling though backends until you find one that works with your installation

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks a lot for your help. I installed tkinter in the bash terminal using `apt-get install python3-tk` (from the link you sent me) and it seemed to have worked, as I can now display graphs. Also I don't need to import tkinter in my script.

Comment: @G.Anderson: I ran the script to cycle through the different backends. It turns out that only TkAgg Is Available ! Indeed, I had just installed it prior to testing the script.

Comment: Modern matplotlib versions will automatically cycle through available toolkits; so if tkinter isn't installed (and none of the other options are) it will fall back to `agg` backend.

Comment: On arch linux, `pacman -S --needed python-pyqt5` fixed the problem.

Comment: I face a similar problem and have managed to use anything **but** `Tcl/Tk` with python as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367570/1147688). IMO there must be a way to load Tcl/Tk as an external DLL and use the `tkinter` as an alias.

Answer (score 601, accepted):

#### Solution 1: is to install the GUI backend `tk`

I found a solution to my problem (thanks to the help of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)).

All I had to do was to install `tkinter` through the Linux bash terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

instead of installing it with `pip` or directly in the virtual environment in Pycharm.

#### Solution 2: install any of the `matplotlib` supported GUI backends

- solution 1 works fine because you get a GUI backend... in this case the `TkAgg`
- however you can also fix the issue by installing any of the matplolib GUI backends like `Qt5Agg`, `GTKAgg`, `Qt4Agg`, etc

  - for example `pip install pyqt5` will fix the issue also

NOTE:

- usually this error appears when you pip install matplotlib and you are trying to display a plot in a GUI window and you do not have a python module for GUI display.
- The authors of `matplotlib` made the pypi software deps not depend on any GUI backend because some people **need** `matplotlib` without any GUI backend.

Comment: Actually, I also realised that since I installed tkinter, I don't need to add the first two lines of my code anymore (`import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`)

Comment: For completeness, under OpenSuse Leap the package I had to install is called `python3-matplotlib-tk`.

Comment: This answer could probably mention that `tkinter` is python version-specific in the sense that this particular command will install `tkinter` exclusively for your default version of python. Suppose you have different python versions installations for various virtual envs. In that case, you will have to install it for the desired python version used in that working venv. For example, in my case: `sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk`. Not knowing this made me struggle a reasonable amount of time getting no module name ' tkinter'  errors, even after installing it for my global python version.

Comment: I had to install a Linux Bash Terminal on my PC in order to run this command. And it worked! See https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: Or use `sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk` if your python version is 3.8

Comment: `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` gave `[Previous line repeated 987 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` for me. I 'fixed' it by starting a new Python Console (in PyCharm).

Comment: For Fedora:

sudo dnf install python3-tkinter

Comment: pip how install tkinter? there are no corresponding item in search results.

Comment: For me, "pip install tk" did not work (Im using windows 10). What worked is reinstalling pythin through downloaded executable, with the option "Modify", and then checking "tcl/tk and IDLE" checkbox.

Comment: I have python 3.10 and on arch linux this works fine ``pip install pyqt5``

Comment: Thanks !!    pip install pyqt5  working for me python 3.9 , ubuntu 21.10    (but not sudo apt-get install python3-tk  )

Comment: If you still facing this problem, be sure to put %matplotlib inline in your notebook AFTER the imports

Answer (score 144):

In my case, the error message was implying that I was working in a headless console. So `plt.show()` could not work. What worked was calling `plt.savefig`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [5, 7, 4])
plt.savefig("mygraph.png")
```

I found the answer on a [github repository](https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn/issues/3#issuecomment-414562934).

Comment: It doesn't really solve the underlying problem, but in my case this is the preferred solution in that it is better to save the image rather than show it, and this will often be the case.

Answer (score 59):

If you use Arch Linux (distributions like `Manjaro` or `Antegros`) simply type:

```
sudo pacman -S tk
```

And all will work perfectly!

Comment: I'm afraid to say this is like the 3rd time I end up here. Perhaps by commenting on it, I stand a better chance of remembering the "trick" next time I try this again...

Comment: From Manjero with XFCE.

This works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

Simple install

```
pip3 install PyQt5==5.9.2
```

It works for me.

Comment: Yup, it works! I installed it inside my virtual env via PyCharm's terminal.

Comment: I execute "pip3 install PyQt5" without specifying version number.

Comment: This is the only answer solved my problem

Comment: Dont know how this is not approved. Only this method worked

Comment: I do not have tk installed and use latest and greatest (3.11.1) via pyenv. This worked

Comment: By doing this, matplotlib would use `Qt5Agg` backend. You can look at @johnwolf1987's answer for better understanding of why this works.

Answer (score 35):

Try `import tkinter` because pycharm already installed tkinter for you, I looked [Install tkinter for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

You can maybe try:

```py
import tkinter
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.plot([1,2,3],[5,7,4])
plt.show()
```

as a tkinter-installing way

I've tried your way, it seems no error to run at my computer, it successfully shows the figure. maybe because pycharm have tkinter as a system package, so u don't need to install it. But if u can't find tkinter inside, you can go to [Tkdocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) to see the way of installing tkinter, as it mentions, tkinter is a core package for python.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not work (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`). I will try to install tkinter some other way.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem...I'm using linux so I have used this command to install the tkinter `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: I have this issue which previously doesn't happen to me.

I am using VS-code studio on Mac.

Comment: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.

Answer (score 30):

I added `%matplotlib inline`
and my plot showed up in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: This one finally worked for me after trying out everything else (installing tk, pyqt5, .use('tkagg'), manual imports, etc.). I use VSCode on Windows.

Answer (score 20):

I too had this issue in PyCharm. This issue is because you don't have tkinter module in your machine.

To install follow the steps given below (select your appropriate os)

For ubuntu users

```
 sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

For Centos users

```
 sudo yum install python-tkinter
```

or

```
 sudo yum install python3-tkinter
```

for Arch Users

```
  sudo pacman -S tk
```

or

```
  sudo pamac install tk
```

For Windows, use pip to install tk

After installing tkinter restart your Pycharm and run your code, it will work

Answer (score 12):

This worked with R reticulate. Found it [here](https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn/issues/3).

`1: matplotlib.use( 'tkagg' )`
or
`2: matplotlib$use( 'tkagg' )`

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use( 'tkagg' )


style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm

x = [1, 5, 1.5, 8, 1, 9]
y = [2, 8, 1.8, 8, 0.6, 11]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because it specifically suggests an approach (`matplotlib.use( 'tkagg' )`) that OP already tried unsuccessfully. The question is about a) how to fix Tkinter so that this backend will work *or* b) how to use a different backend.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 10, if using `pip install tk` does not work for you, try:

- Download and run official python installer for windows. Even if you
  already have it downloaded, run it again.
- When (re)installing python, make sure you chose "advanced" options, and
  **set the checkbox "tcl/tk and IDLE" to true.**
- If you already had python installed, select the "Modify" option, and
  make sure that checkbox is selected.

Source of my fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59970646/2506354

Comment: This was exactly the problem I had.  Re-downloading the python installer for windows and adding this to the python installation via modify (after it had upgraded).  No re-creation of virtualenvs was required.

Answer (score 4):

I installed `python3-tk` , on Ubuntu 20.04 and using WSL2

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use( 'tkagg')
```

and then I installed [GWSL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/gwsl/9nl6kd1h33v3?cid=storebadge&activetab=pivot:overviewtab#) from the Windows Store which seems to solve problem of WSL2 rendering out of the box

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers worked for me using Pycharm Professional edition 2021.3

Regular matplotlib graphs did work on the scientific view, but it did not allow me to add images to the plots.

What did work for me is adding this line before I try plotting anything:

`plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')`

Answer (score 3):

issue = “UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.”

*And this worked for me*

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04, PyCharm Prof

Comment: I think this is actually the right solution, because it is the easiest. Only need to install it where needed, e.g. by running : pip3 install PyQt5

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @xicocaio should be highlighted.

tkinter is python version-specific in the sense that `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` will install tkinter exclusively for your default version of python. Suppose you have different python versions within various virtual environments, you will have to install tkinter for the desired python version used in that virtual environment. For example, `sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk`. Not doing this will still lead to `No module named ' tkinter'` errors, even after installing it for the global python version.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by putting `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` after all import statements.
I use python 3.8.5 VSCODE and anaconda.
No other tricks worked.

Comment: This does not answer the question, because it describes something that OP already tried unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS, I made it work with:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if this helps anybody.

Python version: 3.7.7
platform: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

This came with default python version 3.6.9, however I had installed my own 3.7.7 version python on it (installed building it from source)

tkinter was not working even when the `help('module')` shows tkinter in the list.

The following steps worked for me:

1. `sudo apt-get install tk-dev.`

rebuild the python:
1. Navigate to your python folder and run the checks:

```
cd Python-3.7.7
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

2. Build using make command:
   `sudo make -j 8`    --- here 8 are the number of processors, check yours using `nproc` command.
3. Installing using:

   ```
   sudo make altinstall
   ```

Don't use sudo make install, it will overwrite default 3.6.9 version, which might be messy later.

4. Check tkinter now

   ```
   python3.7 -m tkinter
   ```

A windows box will pop up, your tkinter is ready now.

Answer (score 1):

## On WSL with X server

Make sure that your X server work. Matplotlib indicate this error if he can't connect to the X display.

### Windows Firewall configuration

Pay attention to the windows firewall ! I changed from WSL Debian to Ubuntu and didn't remember about the firewall rule.
I use [this post](https://thomasward.com/wsl2-x11/#configure-windows-firewall) to configure the windows firewall rule to make the X server work. This method avoid too permisive rule that able anyone to use your X server.

It said :

> If you already had installed an X11 server, Windows may have created firewall rules that will mess with the above configuration. Search for them and delete them in "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security."

> You will now need to configure Windows Firewall to permit connections from WSL2 to the X11 display server. You will install the display server in the next step. We do this step first to avoid Windows Firewall from auto-creating an insecure firewall rule when you run the X11 display server. Many guides on X11 forwarding and WSL2 make this firewall rule too permissive, allowing connections from any computer to your computer. This means someone could theoretically, if they are on your same network, start sending graphical display information to your computer.
>
> To avoid this, we will make Windows Firewall only accept internet traffic from the WSL2 instance.
>
> To set this up, you can copy the below to a script and run it from within WSL2:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> LINUX_IP=$(ip addr | awk '/inet / && !/127.0.0.1/ {split($2,a,"/"); print a[1]}')
> WINDOWS_IP=$(ip route | awk '/^default/ {print $3}')
> # Elevate to administrator status then run netsh to add firewall rule
> powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process netsh.exe -ArgumentList \"advfirewall firewall add rule name=X11-Forwarding dir=in action=allow program=%ProgramFiles%\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe localip=$WINDOWS_IP remoteip=$LINUX_IP localport=6000 protocol=tcp\" -Verb RunAs"
> ```

Manual method :

> Alternatively, you can manually add the rule through a GUI by doing the following:
>
> 1. Open "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security"
> 2. Click add new rule brings up the New Rule Wizard (next to navigate between each section):
>
>    - Rule type: Custom
>    - Program: "This program path:" %ProgramFiles%\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe
>    - Protocol and ports
>    - Protocol type: TCP
>    - Local port: 6000
>    - Remote port: any
>    - Scope
>
>      - Local IP address: Obtain the IP address to put in by running the below command in WSL2
>        `ip route | awk '/^default/ {print $3}'`
>    - remote IP addresses
>
>      - Obtain IP address to enter by running the below in WSL2
>        `ip addr | awk '/inet / && !/127.0.0.1/ {split($2,a,"/"); print a[1]}'`
>    - Action: "Allow the connection
>    - Profile: Selection Domain, Private, and Public
>    - Name: "X11 forwarding"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31039990)

Answer (score 0):

If you install python versions using **pyenv** on Debian-based systems, be sure to run `sudo apt install tk-dev` before `pyenv install`. If it's already installed, remove it with `pyenv uninstall` and install it again after install `tk-dev`. Therefore, there is no need to set any env variables when running `pyenv install`.

Answer (score 0):

Running
**%matplotlib inline**
Once fixed the problem for me.
I found the answer here: [When I use matplotlib in jupyter notebook,it always raise " matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365357/when-i-use-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebook-it-always-raise-matplotlib-is-curren)
by user Mulugeta Weldezgina

> adding %matplotlib inline while importing helps for smooth plots in
> notebook

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

> %matplotlib inline sets the backend of matplotlib to the 'inline'
> backend:
> With this backend, the output of plotting commands is displayed inline
> within frontends like the Jupyter notebook, directly below the code
> cell that produced it. The resulting plots will then also be stored in
> the notebook document.

My problem started after I used pandas_profile (or something like that), and running  `%matplotlib inline`  once fixed the background from being headless etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 command line setup.  I install the following to make Matplotlib stop throwing the error `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`

I installed python-tk through the steps:

```
apt-get update

apt-get install python3.8-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, check this box during setup:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Linux Mint 19. Helped for me:

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

P.S. Recompile python interpreter after package install.

Answer (score -1):

After upgrading lots of packages (`Spyder` 3 to 4, `Keras` and `Tensorflow` and lots of their dependencies), I had the same problem today! I cannot figure out what happened; but the (conda-based) virtual environment that kept using `Spyder` 3 did not have the problem. Although installing `tkinter` or changing the backend, `via matplotlib.use('TkAgg)` as shown above, or this nice post on  [how to change the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193/how-to-change-backends-in-matplotlib-python),  might well resolve the problem, I don't see these as rigid solutions. For me, uninstalling `matplotlib` and reinstalling it was magic and the problem was solved.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

... then, install

```
pip install matplotlib
```

From all the above, this could be a package management problem, and BTW, I use both `conda` and `pip`, whenever feasible.

Answer (score -1):

When I ran into this error on Spyder, I changed from running my code line by line to highlighting my block of plotting code and running that all at once. Voila, the image appeared.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the matplotlib using backend using the from `agg` to Tkinter `TKAgg` using command

```
matplotlib.use('TKAgg',warn=False, force=True)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, because it describes an approach that OP already tried unsuccessfully before posting.

Answer (score -1):

Works if you use some third party code in your project. It probably contains the following line

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Search for it and comment it out.

If you have no clue about what it is you are probably not using this part of the code.

Solutions about using another backend GUI may be cleaner, so choose your fighter.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Install tkinter
2. import tkinter into the module
3. make sure that matplotlib uses (TkAgg) instead of (Agg)

   matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

Comment: This does not answer the question, because it describes an approach that OP already tried unsuccessfully before asking. (It also effectively duplicates a couple other answers.)

Answer (score -1):

Beware of the import order in your code, I spent a whole day going through this answers and ended up solving the problem by importing bt before anything else and then using the `.use('TkAgg')` statement (for some reason importing bt changes the matplotlib backend to 'Agg')

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). It is a useful software where you can create many environments and there are many libraries already installed for data science and machine learning.

--Edit --

Here there are steps that help me to fix your same issue:

- **Step 1:** Download .exe on the official page: [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), use the individual edition because it is the free ones: [Anaconda Individual](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)
- **Step 2:** Once you have installed the program, open in end go to the env section
  [image]

In this section, you can create many env as you prefer, i.e I have 2 env one for my main base (root) one for the last version of python.

- **Step 3:** creating the py env in this section, Anaconda will install automatically the main libraries used by developers, decreasing the risk of getting Errors on your code.
- **Additional Consideration**: as you can see in the snap below you can easily see which libraries have you installed in your conda. I got your same that error because i missed one of that 3 libs
  [image]

Hope was useful and clear to understand!
Cya

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30066500)

Comment: Sir, Q: he was not able to see the chart correctly. A: By installing the software you are able to fix that problem. I had the same problem and this was how I fixed it in my personal experience. Thanks.

Comment: Then please [edit] to add more details and steps to your answer, which is basically "install anaconda". Installing Anaconda is *just the 1st step*. How does it solve the problem with matplotlib and tkinter? How do they install the other packages? What specific commands do they need to run? It's missing some more details to make it a full answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem with Windows 7 and PyCharm Pro.
It happened after I'd installed the financial package "ffn", so after

```
import ffn
```

the Matplotlib backend had changed to "add".
You can check the current backend by:

```
matplotlip.get_backend()
```

You can change the current backend by:

```
matplotlib.use(backend = "module://backend_interagg")
```

Which worked for my issue with PyCharm Professional in an additional or internal window.

Answer (score -1):

the solution of this problem is:
make sure put  this line

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in the head of your code

like that

```
# In an IPython notebook¶
# This magic just sets up matplotlib's interactive mode
%matplotlib inline
# So you have to explicitely import the module into the namespace
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
# Create the figure object
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
pl.plot(x, y)
```

**%matplotlib inline turns on “inline plotting”, where plot graphics will appear in your notebook. This has important implications for interactivity: for inline plotting, commands in cells below the cell that outputs a plot will not affect the plot. For example, changing the color map is not possible from cells below the cell that creates a plot. However, for other backends, such as qt4, that open a separate window, cells below those that create the plot will change the plot - it is a live object in memory. If you are not using matplotlib in interactive mode at all, figures will only appear if you invoke**

for more information about %matplotlib inline  see this [link](https://docs.wradlib.org/en/stable/notebooks/python/mplintro.html)