# Error message in python plot using skfuzzy package

Tags: python, skfuzzy

I am running "Fuzzy Control Systems: The Tipping Problem" posted [here](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html) as an example.It works fine but displays following error message in plots. I need your help to fix this. I searched everywhere without any success.

C:\Users\Home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skfuzzy\control\fuzzyvariable.py:122: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
fig.show()

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so

Comment: When I use matplotlib.use( 'TkAgg' ), it gives more errors.

Comment: I have also checked tkinter is installed. Few top error lines are:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 259, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\Home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Users\Home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so)

Comment: I found the solution. I am using spyder IDE and I needed to change the graphic backend option to Automatics in IPython console. It works now without any error.