# correlation heatmap in python

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation

sounds like a simple enough task, but it is not working and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create a correlation heatmap. I use the code below:

```
sns.heatmap(df.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1));
```

and simply nothing happens. when I then do the below:

```
hmap = sns.heatmap(df.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1));
hmap
```

I get the output as:

```
<AxesSubplot:title={'center':'Triangle Correlation Heatmap'}>
```

can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the plt.show() method to display the plot. Try integrating the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(df.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I still dont see the map. I get the below:

UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()

Comment: Weird, this works for me. How are you running your python script, are you using any kind of IDE or jupyter notebook

Comment: There is some more information which looks relevant to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spectrapepper](https://github.com/spectrapepper/spectrapepper) for this:

```
import spectrapepper as spep

# load sample data from the library
data = spep.load_params()

# labels
labels = ['T', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'S1', 'R1', 'R2', 'ETA', 'FF', 'JSC', 'ISC', 'VOC']

# plot spearman
spep.spearman(data, labels)

# plot person
spep.pearson(data, labels)
```

The above is extracted for the [documentation](https://spectrapepper.github.io/spectrapepper/examples.html) of the library. These functions automatically plot the heatmap and also return it in the form of a list for you to use the data after if you do:

```
heatmap = spep.spearman(data, labels)
```

You can print out the variable `data` to see what is the accepted format.