# Python3 plot not showing in WSL

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm pretty new to Python. I have a simple script that shows a simple plot on the console. It works perfectly when I execute the script in VSCode, and the plots shows up as expected.  However, when running the same script in Python in WSL, the plot doesn't show up, and I also don't get any error messages.

I'm on Windows 10.

Here is my code snippet that I typed directly in Python under WSL:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [x**2 for x in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f57445be700>] # I get this message and I don't know what this means.
plt.show() # No error message, but the plot doesn't show up in my console.
```

Again, the plot shows up when I execute the script in VSCode.

How can I display the plot under WSL?

Comment: When I run your code in my terminal (on Mac), the plot appears in another window but not in the console itself. Is it possible that the plot _is_ opening, but is opening somewhere you are not looking?

Comment: Add `plt.show()` statement at the end. And read Matplotlib docs,

Comment: If you are running Bash inside WSL, it probably doesn't know how to talk to the Windows GUI. Or are you on Linux or a Mac?

Comment: @jhschwartz that's my initial thought as well, but I don't see it anywhere. It's interesting because when I run the same code in regular command prompt (not bash), the plot shows up.

Comment: @tripleee that's exactly what i'm doing, I'm running Bash in WSL. I'm on Windows10. First time user of WSL/Bash too. Any other prompts to the WSL environment to show the plot? I tried adding plt.ion() but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Going forward, please [edit] your question rather than respond in comments.

Comment: I have little to no experience using WSL so I can't help with that unfortunately. What I can do, though, is *strongly* recommend that you use jupyter notebooks for plotting instead of trying to do it right from the command line. Or, download the ubuntu app on Windows--maybe that will make things easier. But if you must use WSL I wish you luck!

Comment: @YuriGinsburg You know, it's odd that I missed it my first several read-throughs as well, but the original post *does* already have `plt.show()` at the end ;-).

Comment: @jhschwartz *"Or, download the ubuntu app on Windows"* -- The Ubuntu "app" (found in the Store) actually *is* running on WSL, unless you are referring to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that your MRE works in Visual Studio Code, I'm guessing:

- You are using the Windows version of Python in VSCode
- Or you are using [Jupyter Notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) there.

Edit:  I just noticed your comment:

> It's interesting because when I run the same code in regular command prompt (not bash), the plot shows up

So yes, it appears that you are *also* running the Windows version of Python.  You *can* use WSL inside of VSCode, but that's not what you doing in this case, it seems.

---

Under WSL, there may be several things you need to do, depending on your Windows version:

- First, Windows 11 is recommended here, since it includes built-in support for displaying Linux GUI applications.

  Older versions of WSL on Windows 10 do not support this directly.  On Windows 10, you'll need to either install a third-party X server or use XRDP.  The easiest way to do this (other than Windows 11) is with [Xfce4 + XRDP](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365455/1165986), but it's definitely the slowest method as well.  Also see my answer on [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393173/1165986).

  Since you are on Windows 10, you'll have to get GUI support working first on WSL.  Test with something like `xterm` to make sure you have it working) and then come back here.

---

> `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f57445be700>]`
>
> I get this message and I don't know what this means.

That's an easy one.  When you are entering code directly into the Python REPL, it will always show the value/return-result for each line.  All of the other lines that you typed up to that point either had no return result or you stored the return value in a variable.  In the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot), you'll notice that the return value from `plot` is a "list of `Line2D`" objects.

You could suppress the message by simply storing the result in a variable, but there's no need for this in the REPL.

---

> `plt.show()`
>
> No error message, but the plot doesn't show up in my console.

Hmmm.  When I try that in a base Ubuntu 22.04 distribution under WSL, I *do* get an error message:

```
<stdin>:1: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

Since you aren't receiving an error, it appears (from the doc) that Matplotlib is detecting some GUI environment and auto-selecting a higher-precedent [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) because of this:

> Without a backend explicitly set, Matplotlib automatically detects a usable backend based on what is available on your system and on whether a GUI event loop is already running. The first usable backend in the following list is selected: MacOSX, QtAgg, GTK4Agg, Gtk3Agg, TkAgg, WxAgg, Agg. The last, Agg, is a non-interactive backend that can only write to files. It is used on Linux, if Matplotlib cannot connect to either an X display or a Wayland display.

But I don't know why you aren't getting an error (but also no display) on that backend.  It might be useful to run `plt.get_backend()` to see which backend Matplotlib has auto-selected.  For me, on a freshly installed Ubuntu, that's `agg`, but it sounds like that's going to be different for you.

---

Regardless, that brings us to the next likely step -- Make sure that all dependencies for a Matplotlib GUI backend are enabled.  This includes:

- The Linux libraries needed for the selected backend.
- The Python modules needed for the selected backend.

On a *typical* Ubuntu installation, the Linux libraries would already be installed, since Linux desktop installations are running GUI's.  However, the Ubuntu/WSL distributions are based on Ubuntu Server, and don't include any graphical apps out-of-the-box.

Assuming you want to use the Qt5 backend, which is the highest priority other than Mac in the Matplotlib auto-select list, we'll need to install those libraries:

```
sudo apt install libqt5gui5
```

Then, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675620/11810933), you'll need the Python support for Qt5:

```
# Don't do this yet.  Read next step.
pip install pyqt5
```

Note:  It's recommended that you do this in a virtual environment (venv) so that you don't "pollute" your system Python installation with unnecessary libraries.  Since you are new to Python, I'm going to recommend that you read-up on [Python virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), but here's the summary to get started:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
cd <project_dir>
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Your prompt should change to include `(.venv)` to show that the environment is active.

Then, anything you `pip install` will be in that virtual environment rather than your system environment:

```
# Now we can do this "safely"
pip install pyqt5
python3
```

With this in place, try your code again.  Hopefully, you should now see that `plt.get_backend()` returns `qtAgg`.  If not, then there's additional troubleshooting to do.

And with that in place, `plt.plot()` should (it does for me) display the plot directly on the screen.