# RE: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.plt.show() in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

[Previously Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56656777/13436929)

The answers given are great, however they only address the problem in the form of Python/Linux Terminal commands. i.e., sudo install ....

What about when I am in a IDE such as PyCharm? I could use the Python Console to make the necessary changes, but there seems to be more straight forward ways to do simply change the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I found [examples and answers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/index.html)

Is there some reason I should not just use the examples here;
for example:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
```

The simplest answer to this question would be "There is no downside to doing it that way."

Thanks.