# Unable to import matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I have installed python 2.7.10 in CentOS 6.5. Then I installed matplotlib using pip. However, I am getting the following error when trying to import matplotlib.pyplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

tkinter seems to be installed.
"Package tkinter-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

I have _tkinter.so module in python2.6/lib-dynload, but nothing related to tkinter under python2.7/lib-dynload.

/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/test/test_tkinter

Also, I verified sys.path in python to get the following:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2017, 18:51:46)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/lib/python27.zip  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: How did you get Python 2.7 on CentOS 6? Or, if you don't need a UI, you can change your backend to just render PNGs/PDFs with `import matplotlib;matplotlib.use('agg')` before other imports (see [What is a backend?](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)).

Comment: @NickT - I have manually installed 2.7.10. I have followed a few sources but mostly this: http://blog.ruterly.com/2015/12/03/Update-python/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk
Check this out. This explains what wrong with unable to import tkinter

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with your python library path.  Check to see *where* tkinter is installed, and make sure that you have that available to your Python interpreter.  Can you import anything else from `tkinter`?

Comment: I have added some more details which might be relevant to what you have asked. Thanks.

Comment: May be your both python2.6 and python2.7 have packages, which are not compatible with each other.Why dont you uninstall python2.6,this may solve your problem .Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install tkinter as they said ”no module named _tkinter“.
You can do so with that command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Comment: `apt-get` is for Debian-likes, while he has CentOS 6 that'll be using `yum` and has different package names

Comment: @utopia - as mentioned in the details, tkinter seems to be installed.
"Package tkinter-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version"