# Python Interpreter: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I run `import tkinter` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Ruuning `apt-get install python3-tk` doesn't sove this issue.

Running Python 3.9 on Debian Experimental

Comment: Pick one from: [`"No module named '_tkinter'"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+%22No+module+named+%27_tkinter%27%22)

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk

Comment: "Ruuning apt-get install python3-tk doesn't sove this issue. " That is because this can **only** add Tkinter support for the **system** Python, but the path `/usr/local/lib/python3.9` tells us that this is a separately installed Python. It must instead be recompiled with Tkinter support. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try `import tkinter` instead of `import _tkinter`

Comment: @Bryan Oakley that's why, so  `import tkinter` instead of `import _tkinter`

Comment: They are importing tkinter; tkinter imports _tkinter. The very first line of the question says they are importing tkinter.