# import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk error in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, ubuntu-20.04

**Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with python3.8.5.**
Its my first time using ubuntu with absolutely no previous knowledge of terminal.SO,would love to have a detailed answer if possible.
Below is terminal output when i try importing tkinter in python3.

```
>>> import tkinter  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>>
```

I have reinstalled python3 and tkinter using sudo apt.But still it shows same error.
When i run the same command in python IDLE it works without any error.
I hope this explains my problem clearly, if any other info. is required pls reply.
[I also tried running the command >>>from tkinter import *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFx9G.png)

Comment: Try doing:

sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Comment: Thanks, but i have already installed it with the same command and when i try running the command again it shows that i already have the latest version of it

Comment: If you built python 3.8 from source you may need to recompile it.  Be sure to check the output of the `configure` script for messages about which modules it cannot install.

Comment: @snakecharmerb i used make command to rebuild the install yet i am getting same error

Comment: Maybe you could install tkinter with `pip install tkinter`  (or pip3). Maybe you have already installed pip while installing python, if not, just run `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: @EricRoy the command 'pip3 install tkinter' gave this WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Comment: @EricRoy the command 'sudo apt-get install python3-pip' gave this output **python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1).**

Comment: This may help you, in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue it occurred because the Tkinter was installed for version 3.5 and not for the 3.8 version. For that, I installed the 3.5 version and kept only one version i.e. 3.8, and installed Tkinter again, and it worked!
This is just a workaround to make things work, but the more preferred way is to create a venv and then install the particular versions of python and libraries that are needed.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue on MacOS. I was using a Python virtual environment. This command worked for me:

```
brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 3):

since I'm still using python 3.9, this code works for me:

`brew install python-tk@3.9`

if using `brew install python-tk` brew will install python-tk@3.10 which is key-only

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 8 + Python 3.9.5
following are what i have done：

> 1st:

```
yum search tkinter
yum install python39-tkinter.x86_64
```

> 2nd:

```
yum install tk-devel
```

> 3rd: cd python3.9.5 source folder

```
make install
```

it work in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Switched from 3.8 to 3.7 and it worked. I'm using PyCharm CE, which makes it easy to switch between interpreters.