# delphi app with python4delphi , fails at UNIX computer with -> EPyValueError with Message

Tags: python, delphi

I run an Delphi application using Python4Delphi under WINDOWS and LINUX.
Execution on WINDOWS works as expected
Execution on LINUX returned the  following error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2349, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ValueError: character U+68002f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff
```

the code uses numpy and mathplotlib, both packages are installed
I installed tkinter  on my LINUX computing system

[image: error @ WINDOWS debugger]

Comment: Any luck with:  [Tkinter: “Python may not be configured for Tk”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/)?

Comment: Are you able to run Python programs that use Tkinter on the Linux system?