# How to re-build python without removing the packages installed

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I use pyenv to manage my python versions as well as their virtual environments. Sometimes I ran into problems, of which the solution requires building python after installing certain dependencies.

So I simply run

```bash
pyenv uninstall 3.8.12
```

and install the dependencies required, then

```bash
pyenv install 3.8.12
```

however, this operation removes all the package installed along with the entire virtual environment under

```bash
pyenvrootdir/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12
```

in the previous version, like numpy or matplotlib.

So is there any way to remove, then re-build python, while those packages remains, so that I don't need to install them again?

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv with pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Then you can just write, uninstall only needed if you like to delete it:

```
pyenv install 3.11.2
pyenv virtualenv 3.11.2 test1
pyenv activate test1
pyenv uninstall test1
```

To install a new one, just deactivate the current:

```
pyenv deactivate
pyenv virtialenv 3.11.2 mynewapp
pyenv activate mynewapp
```

It is not uncommon having lots of virtualenvs.

Comment: Thank you for answering:)
Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the problem I ran into requires uninstall -> reinstall the python interpreter itself. When I remove python 3.8.12 (by running pyenv uninstall), all virtualenvs under 3.8.12 will be removed as well. What I am trying to find is a way to rebuild the python interpreter, while the virtualenv and packages under it remains. I wonder if it's possible.

My problem was [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk), to be specific.

Comment: You should not delete a python version until all virtualenvs using is are deleted. Check with `pyenv versions`, but you can have lots of python versions installed '`pyenv install <pythonversion>`installs it alongside the others. If you just work with the virtualenv names not python version it will all be fine.