# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' when installing python 3.12.0 using pyenv in Fedora 38

Tags: python, tkinter, pyenv

I'm tryiny to install latest python 3.12.0 in Fedora 38 using pyenv. The command is `pyenv install 3.12.0`

I get below error -

```bash
~ pyenv install 3.12.0  
  Downloading Python-3.12.0.tar.xz...
  -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.0/Python-3.12.0.tar.xz
  Installing Python-3.12.0...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/raj/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
      import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
  WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
  Installed Python-3.12.0 to /home/raj/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0
```

I also installed tkinter in fedora but its version is 3.11.6.

```bash
 ~ sudo dnf install python3-tkinter -y        
  Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:18 ago on Tue 17 Oct 2023 09:30:15 PM PDT.
  Package python3-tkinter-3.11.6-1.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.
  Dependencies resolved.
```

How can I fix this error?

Note:

**OS Details**

```bash
~ lsb_release -a     
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)
Release:        38
Codename:       ThirtyEight
```

**pyenv version**

```bash
~ pyenv --version    
pyenv 2.3.30
```

Comment: You need to have the development packages of `tcl` and `tk` installed in order to build the tkinter module when building Python from source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk

Comment: If you follow the official document on [installing required packages](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment), you should install Python 3.12.0 with tkinter successful via `pyenv`.

Comment: pyenv install 3.12.0rc3

Answer (score 2):

Update your system's package list and install the required packages

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install tk-devel
```

Set the TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY environment variables. You can do this in your shell configuration file (e.g., ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc) or set them temporarily for your session. Replace <path_to_tcl> and <path_to_tk> with the actual paths

```
export TCL_LIBRARY="<path_to_tcl>/lib"
export TK_LIBRARY="<path_to_tk>/lib"
```

Open a new terminal to apply changes

```
pyenv install 3.12.0
```

This should allow you to build Python 3.12.0 with Tkinter support

Comment: Had the same problem on Ubuntu, solved with `apt install tk-dev python3-tk`

Answer (score 0):

You can run into this on macOS as well (which brought me here), e.g.:

```
python-build: use openssl@3 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.12.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/Python-3.12.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.2...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Installed Python-3.12.2 to /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2
```

Note a line is missing: `python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew`.
As https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment suggests, in addition to XCode Command Line tools, you should probably have:
`brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib tcl-tk`

Re-running `python install 3.12` after installing `tcl-tk` should do the trick.