# Not able to use tkinter in Mac OS Sonoma 14.4.1 and vscode

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

guys, i'm new here, so i hope im writting a question that follows the good manners.

I have a Mac OS Sonoma 14.4.1, fully updated and just finished a Python Dev course, so really new to all of it.

Sorry for any good manner trouble i may cause with my post, and i actually searched for people with the same error but most its in windows and maybe not found the correctly post.

**I'm running Python 3.12.2 on mac, trying to use tkinter with the code bellow:**

```
import tkinter

janela =Tk()

janela.title()
```

It's a simple line of a tkinter course.

**But its returning this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luisfelipesouzacardoso/Documents/python/TKINTER_PROJECT/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/Users/luisfelipesouzacardoso/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
```

I'm trying to read the traceback correctly, even with chatgpt teaching me what possibily could mean everyline of the error, and i already installed the
`pip install tk`, same for tkinter, following some sugestions in internet, but i'm so newbie that i'm kinda lost and stucked.

Other libraries works fine thought.

Comment: try running `brew install python-tk` on your env and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: "Python may not be configured for Tk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444/tkinter-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk)

Comment: Says it's already installed. I reinstalled anyways but error continues the same.