# TypeError constructor returned NULL while importing pyplot in ssh

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, ssh

I am having difficulties importing `matplotlib.pyplot` when I am using ssh to access my local lab cluster.

Indeed, trying to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is giving me an error. I have tried to just `import matplotlib as mpl` and this is fine, so something specifically about importing `pyplot` is wrong here. The last line of the trace-back says

`File '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py', 
line 58, in <module>
    cursors.MOVE             : Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.FLEUR),
TypeError: constructor returned NULL`

Can anyone identify the error here? Or, is there a way I can circumvent the error and still use the `pyplot` tools?

If it makes a difference, I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Note that this Error will not happen under all circumstances if you have no X server (so don't rely on catching it). Depending on the version of some library (I guess), you might as well get an TclError  when you call plt.subplots() (see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4931376/5069869)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are failing to load GTK.  Most likely, it is because you do not have access to an X11 server and can't draw windows (which is what GTK does).

Try `matplotlib.use("Pdf")` before importing `pyplot`.  Then you won't need to load GTK and it won't fail.  You can still make plots and save them to pdf but you can't draw them on screen.

Alternatively, you could try forwarding X11.  Then you could see the windows as if you were on the host machine.  With a Linux client, this is done by logging on via `ssh -X hostname`.  With a Windows client, [it can be done](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) but not as smoothly.

Comment: In this context, I've found the line `if 'DISPLAY' not in os.environ: matplotlib.use('Pdf')` very useful to autodetect the lack of an X11. Of course you need to `import os, matplotlib` beforehand and `import matplotlib.pyplot` after.