# can't compile 'fig = plt.figure()' in python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib

Trying

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
```

yields

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 423, in figure
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 79, in new_figure_manager
>       return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 87, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>       window = Tk.Tk()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in **init**
>       self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>   _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Never encountered this error before.
Right now I'm on a windows machine (at home) accessing a ubuntu machine (at work) via ssh. Could this be the reason for the error? matplotlib is of course completely installed on the ubuntu machine at work.

Comment: just to clarify: Do you run the code on ubuntu or does the ssh connection is part of the program?

Comment: I run the code on ubuntu. I connect via ssh -Y 'mylogin' and then run /usr/bin/python 'mypythonfile.py'

Comment: Than I do not think it is a problem with the ssh...

Comment: I went nuts about this error and drove to work to test it. There, my code worked just fine. I tried 'import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' which was suggested [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server) here, but it didn't work neither.