# Import Matplotlib without a display

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I am trying to run a python script on my linux server and make and save some plots. I have installed `ipython` and `pylab` and `matplotlib` but then when I run my script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/dining_hall_graph.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pylab import * 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 265, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

On this line `from pylab import *`

How can I plot and save graphs in my python script that I am running on my linux server?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is with using the `gtk` backend.  Does this answer solve your problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935945/230468

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should almost never use `from pylab import *`.

Import what you need from `numpy`, `scipy` and `matplotlib`.

On machines without display, you need to use the `agg` backend:

You can achieve this by specifying the environmental variable `MPLBACKEND`

```
$ MPLBACKEND=Agg python plot.py
```

Or by importing `matplotlib` *before* importing `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 1])
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

To make this the default, you can create a file called `matplotlibrc`
in the current directory or in `$HOME/.config/matplotlib` with the following content:

```
backend: Agg
```

Or you could enable X-Forwarding, so the plots will pop up on your host machine:

```
ssh -X user@server
```

Comment: great, is it also possible to see the plot in the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean? Ascii-art?

Comment: not that I know of. What is wrong with x-forwarding?