# pydroid showing terminal when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, pydroid

I'm working on a project that creates some graphics using matplotlib in pydroid but I need to see some output in the terminal but when I import matplotlib and run the code it shows the matplotlib GUI window and not the pydroid terminal how can I solve that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/file.csv")
print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Matplotlib without a display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902941/import-matplotlib-without-a-display)

Comment: This problem is totally inacceptable !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Pydroid 3 (version 5.00_arm)  is sensitive to the phrase `import matplotlib` .
For example , if you run this code:

```py3
#import matplotlib
print(3+3)
```

you won't see any result.
If you want to see the terminal output , first run your code and then use `Graphical program output` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: thanks, however I remember I saw something regarding passing a command with the pound sign  to show the terminal when importing matplotlib