# Pyplot "cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0" despite ioff() and matplotlib.use('Agg')

Tags: python, matplotlib, x11, x11-forwarding

I have a piece of code which gets called by a different function, carries out some calculations for me and then plots the output to a file. Seeing as the whole script can take a while to run for larger datasets and since I may want to analyse multiple datasets at a given time I start it in `screen` then disconnect and close my putty session and check back on it the next day. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. My code looks as follows (I have skipped the calculations):

```
import shelve
import os, sys, time
import numpy
import timeit
import logging
import csv
import itertools

import graph_tool.all as gt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ioff()

#Do some calculations

print 'plotting indeg'      
# Let's plot its in-degree distribution
in_hist = gt.vertex_hist(g, "in")

y = in_hist[0]
err = numpy.sqrt(in_hist[0])
err[err >= y] = y[err >= y] - 1e-2

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.errorbar(in_hist[1][:-1], in_hist[0], fmt="o",
        label="in")
plt.gca().set_yscale("log")
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.gca().set_ylim(0.8, 1e5)
plt.gca().set_xlim(0.8, 1e3)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
plt.xlabel("$k_{in}$")
plt.ylabel("$NP(k_{in})$")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("in-deg-dist.png")
plt.close()

print 'plotting outdeg'

#Do some more stuff
```

The script runs perfectly happily until I get to the plotting commands. To try and get to the root of the problem I am currently running it in putty without screen and with no X11 applications. The ouput I get is the following:

```
plotting indeg
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
: cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

I presume this is caused by the code trying to open a window but I thought that by explicitely setting `plt.off()` that would be disabled. Since it wasn't I followed this thread ([Generating matplotlib graphs without a running X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server) ) and specified the backend, but that didn't solve the problem either. Where might I be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling function calls other functions too which also use matplotlib. These get called only after this one but during the `import` statement their dependecies get loaded. Seeing as they were loaded first they disabled the subsequent `matplotlib.use('Agg')` declaration. Moving that declaration to the main script has solved the problem.