# Error only when submitting python job in Slurm

Tags: python, slurm

I am running a python script on a remote machine, which runs fine, but soon after starting I get the warning:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-myusername'
```

I didn't worry about this warning as it wasn't stopping my code.

I then tried to submit the same code using Slurm workload manager, using the command:

```
sbatch --wrap="python mycode.py" -N 1 --cpus-per-task=8 -o mycode.o
```

When I do this, the code doesn't work, and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 99, in <module>
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12), dpi = 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
  File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 539, in figure
**kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3252, in new_figure_manager
return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 946, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
window = tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:36.0"
```

Obvious the error is something to do with a figure I am producing. I'm not sure if it is related to the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR warning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are running requires a XGraphics server to be there, which is there locally for you but on the Slurm server you can connect to

Comment: But I only save some figures (using np.savefig). I'm not doing anything special. – user1551817 13 hours ago - I don't try to output anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is related to below thread

[tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:18.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518352/tkinter-tclerror-couldnt-connect-to-display-localhost18-0)

Solution to change your import like below

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pdf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Few more threads

[Pyplot "cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0" despite ioff() and matplotlib.use('Agg')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612473/pyplot-cannot-connect-to-x-server-localhost10-0-despite-ioff-and-matplotlib)

Comment: Thank you! For me, matplotlib.use('Agg') was the fix, as suggested in one of those threads.