# Matplotlib plot with AGG backend not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there something I am missing? I would like to run software without having to go install a monitor on a virtual machine and hit a key every time it processes another image. The concept of forcing the GUI dependence on the user seems rather odd... Why assume a physical monitor?

I have jumped through the hoops for the "AGG" backend to remove the X server dependence, but this changes nothing. How can I force it to not try and draw to a non-existent display?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from decimal import Decimal
from PIL import Image 
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS 
import time
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



chans = cv2.split(img)
colors = ("b", "g", "r")
plt.figure()
#plt.axis('off')
features = []

# loop over the image channels
for (chan, color) in zip(chans, colors):
    chist = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    features.extend(chist)

# plot the histogram
plt.plot(chist, color = color)
plt.xlim([0, 256])
plt.savefig('histchart.png', bbox_inches=0)
```

No matter what I do, it still forces that stupid GUI dependance. Is there any way to totally and completely remove the dependency?

Comment: In principle your code seems correct, judging from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server). You would need to go into more detail about what is wrong with it, and/or produce a [MCVE]. Because you're not showing the complete code, it may be that you are importing pyplot already beforehands (possibly hidden in some other import?).

Comment: Updated with full imports.
The issue is the unwanted pop up window. I can jump through hoops and make the OS think there is a display, but someone still needs to press a button on the plot to make it go away and let the program continue. 
I struggle to understand why that dependency is built in by default. Which makes it likely that I am missing something.
I also dont understand why using the 'Agg' backend does not solve the issue as advertised. The evidence indicates here as well I am missing something....

Comment: As I said, the code should work. When I add a line to define `img`, like `img = cv2.imread("some_file.png")`, the script runs without displaying anything on the screen. This is on windows 8 with python 2.7, matplotlib 1.5, opencv 2.4. So it may be an issue of your OS? Adding details about your system might help others to reproduce the issue.