# No display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable using tkinter through ssh

Tags: python, numpy, ssh, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to run a very simple code that outputs a .png file in a cluster. Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(60)
y = np.random.randn(60)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=20)

out_png = 'path/to/store/out_file.png'
plt.savefig(out_png, dpi=150)
```

If I run this code with the command `python simple_code.py` in my system which has matplotlib 1.2.1 installed I get the warning:

```
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n:
```

The .png image is still produced so I have no problems here. But if I use the same command and code in a cluster which has matplotlib 1.3.0 installed it fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_code.py", line 33, in <module>
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=20)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3078, in scatter
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 803, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 450, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 423, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 79, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 87, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1712, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

What is happening here?

---

Add, this is the script I use to login into the cluster:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "user"
set addr "address1"
set addr2 "address2"
set pw "password"

spawn ssh -X $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "$login@host:"
send "ssh -X $addr2\r"
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
interact
```

Comment: Are you running this through `ssh`?

Comment: Yes I am SethMMorton. I set the job and let it run in the cluster through `ssh`.

Comment: When you call `ssh`, do you use the `-X` flag?

Comment: Nope, I just call the `ssh` twice with no flag. This question I made yesterday explains how I login: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94334/script-to-login-to-ssh-twice

Comment: I added the `ssh` tag to this post.  I think you should change the title to "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable using tkinter through ssh" because that's the real problem and more easily searchable for others with the same problem (I don't like changing other people's titles.).

Comment: Done Seth, thanks. Please see my comment in your answer.

Comment: The script you are using is not using the `-X` flag...

Comment: That's because that is the *original* script. Let me change it to show how I setup the `-X` flags as you instructed.

Comment: You should call it like `ssh -X ...`, not `ssh ... -X`.  That *might* be the issue.

Comment: That's actually what I tried first and then changed to putting the flag last. That did not work either but I'll edit the question the same.

Comment: I am going to delete my answer and direct you to the following SO question.  It's actually almost an exact duplicate of this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2801882/1399279.  It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Seth, that has apparently fixed the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 36):

Your problem is in ssh command. What you need to do is to write it this way:

```
ssh -X "your_login"
```

Comment: As an FYI, this was not the solution to the OP's problem.  I had suggested in my own answer and then deleted it when the OP told me that it did not fix the problem.  The problem identical to the one given here, and it also contains the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2801882/1399279.

Comment: Just a reminder, `ssh -X` may at times give you warnings like `Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated` in which case you should do `ssh -Y` instead.

Comment: The -Y worked for me (the -X didn't). Thanks @YuxuanChen