# Why does this solve the 'no $DISPLAY environment' issue with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, x11

When running a code that uses the `matplotlib` library in my desktop PC, I have no issues using the line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

far down the code, which is where I actually use the plotting functions.

If I run the code in a server though it will only work if I import `matplotlib` *before*, and force it to use the `Agg` backend. I.e., I have to add the following lines to the beginning of the code:

```
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054314/1391441) where this is explained). Otherwise the code will crash with `TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309085/no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-using-tkinter-through-ssh?lq=1) for example).

The question is: why do I need to do this? The solution works perfectly, but I don't know why I don't have to do this in my desktop PC but I absolutely must when the code runs in the server.

Comment: you could always set the $DISPLAY `export DISPLAY=:0` I think  ...

Comment: I'm not really looking for another way to solve this issue because the current one work works just fine. What I want is to _understand_ why it is working. I don't really understand the alternative solution in your cmmt either BTW :)

Comment: `DISPLAY` is used by the X-Windows system on UNIX/Linux, it is not the fault of matplotlib or Python, just the way things are on that platform.  The reason is flexibility, different displays may be selected depending on the environment variable.

Comment: But I also use Linux on my home PC @cdarke. Why do I have to force `matplotlib` in one system but not on the other? What is being handled differently in both?

Comment: Are you sure DISPLAY is not set by default on your home PC?  It is often set in Linux because the GUI uses it.

Comment: @cdarke unless it is automatically set by python or the system, I do not remember manually setting it to anything.

Comment: Did you see if it is set on your Linux system?  Use the `set` or `env` commands.  It is probably in one of the start-up files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

X11 follows a client/server model, where the X server accepts requests for graphical output from client applications (e.g. interactive matplotlib sessions), and sends back user input from the keyboard, mouse etc. In order for this model to work, client applications need to know which X server to send their requests to. This is controlled by the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. In the case where you are connecting to a remote X session (for example over an SSH connection), the `$DISPLAY` variable in your remote session needs to point to your local X server.

The `$DISPLAY` variable is structured like this:

```
hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
```

Not all parts may be present - the hostname is usually omitted for local sessions, and the screen number is also omitted if there is only one screen. In a local terminal session on laptop, my `$DISPLAY` looks like this:

```
alistair@laptop:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Provided that the remote server also supports X11, it's possible to open graphical windows on the remote machine and have them appear on your local machine using [X11 forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding). For an SSH connection you do this by passing the `-X` (or `-Y`) flag.

For example:

```
alistair@laptop:~$ ssh -X alistair@workstation.address.co.uk
alistair@workstation:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

The remote SSH server should take care of setting the `$DISPLAY` variable appropriately when you open the connection. In this particular case, `localhost:10.0` is actually a 'proxy' X11 server running on the remote machine that listens on display 10 and relays commands to your local X server over the SSH connection ([take a look at this](http://dustwell.com/how-x-over-ssh-really-works.html) if you're interested in the details).

Now you should be able to start a remote IPython session, import matplotlib using an interactive backend, and create plot windows which will then appear on your local machine. Since your keyboard/mouse input and the display output are now passing over an encrypted network connection, the plot windows will be less responsive than you're used to for a local session.

Another word of warning: if you have an IPython session open with an interactive matplotlib session running it is impossible to close the SSH connection without killing the IPython process. I also sometimes call `matplotlib.use("Agg")` before I start a long-running process that imports matplotlib - that way I can disconnect from the remote server without killing the process.