# Why python compiler gives me an error in tkinder module?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, compiler-errors

This is an example code:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
my_label = Label(root, text="Hello World")
my_laber.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

that doesn't work on my terminal: Ubuntu (18.04):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "hello_world.py", line 3, in <module>
        root = Tk() #Setting the windown, to do first.
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
        self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
    _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

How can I fix it?

**Python version**

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273204/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-python; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254530/tkinter-in-ubuntu-inside-windows-10-error-no-display-name-and-no-display-env

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by checking if there's a value assigned to environment variable `DISPLAY` and assigning it if returned string is empty:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY', '') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0')
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

root = Tk()
my_label = Label(root, text="Hello World")
my_label.pack() # watch out here - you have a typo in your code
root.mainloop()
```

You can find more information about the numbers being assigned to `DISPLAY` in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/432257/488419) *ask ubuntu* answer.